# What's the difference between | and || in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we usually use `||` not `|`, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference)

Title says it all.  It's been discussed for other languages, but I haven't seen it for Java yet.