# Do &= and |= short-circuit in Java?

Tags: java, short-circuiting

In other words, do the following two statements behave the same way?

```
isFoobared = isFoobared && methodWithSideEffects();
isFoobared &= methodWithSideEffects();
```

I realize I could just write up a test, but someone might know this offhand, and others might find the answer useful.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No, `|=` and `&=` do not shortcircuit, because they are the compound assignment version of `&` and `|`, which do not shortcircuit.

> #### [JLS 15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2)
>
> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

Thus, assuming `boolean &`, the equivalence for `isFoobared &= methodWithSideEffects()` is:

```
isFoobared = isFoobared & methodWithSideEffects(); // no shortcircuit
```

On the other hand `&&` and `||` do shortcircuit, but inexplicably Java does not have compound assignment version for them. That is, Java has neither `&&=` nor `||=`.

#### See also

- [Shortcut “or-assignment” (|=) operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486472/shortcut-or-assignment-operator-in-java)
- [What’s the difference between | and || in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96667/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-java)
- [Why doesn’t Java have compound assignment versions of the conditional-and and conditional-or operators? (&&=, ||=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324549/why-doesnt-java-have-compound-assignment-versions-of-the-conditional-and-and-con)

---

#### What is this shortcircuiting business anyway?

The difference between the `boolean` logical operators (`&` and `|`) compared to their `boolean` conditional counterparts (`&&` and `||`) is that the former do not "shortcircuit"; the latter do. That is, assuming no exception etc:

- `&` and `|` *always* evaluate both operands
- `&&` and `||` evaluate the right operand *conditionally*; the right operand is evaluated only if its value could affect the result of the binary operation. That means that the right operand is NOT evaluated when:

  - The left operand of `&&` evaluates to `false`

    - (because no matter what the right operand evaluates to, the entire expression is `false`)
  - The left operand of `||` evaluates to `true`

    - (because no matter what the right operand evaluates to, the entire expression is `true`)

#### References

- [JLS 15.22.2 Boolean Logical Operators `&`, `^`, and `|`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2)
- [JLS 15.23 Conditional-And Operator `&&`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23)
- [JLS 15.24 Conditional-Or Operator `||`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.24)

Comment: I don't think it's that inexplicable... As a matter of fact, now that I think about it they would be almost completely useless. The *only* value that would change after assignment is `True and False`. That's 1 out of 8 cases that would render the assignment portion useful. In the 7 other cases there's no need for the result because it won't change. Of course the | and & make sense because you can also use them for bitwise or/and, and hence perform some useful operations.

Comment: I also think it's explicable.  Not that I can, um, explic it, exactly, but I do tend to read assignment statements right-to-left (first do this, then do something with that result) so I'd be very surprised if the LHS magically made the RHS not execute.

Answer (score 4):

No, they do not, because `x &= y` is short for `x = x & y` and `x |= y` is short for `x = x | y`.  Java has no `&&=` or `||=` operators which would do what you want.

The `&` and `|` operators (along with `~`, `^`, `<<`, `>>`, and `>>>`) are the [bitwise operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).  The expression `x & y` will, for *any* integral type, perform a *bitwise* and operation.  Similarly, `|` performs a bitwise or.  To perform a bitwise operation, each bit in the number is treated like a boolean, with `1` indicating `true` and `0` indicating `false`.  Thus, `3 & 2 == 2`, since `3` is `0...011` in binary and `2` is `0...010`.  Similarly, `3 | 2 == 3`.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operator) has a good complete explanation of the different operators.  Now, for a boolean, I *think* you can get away with using `&` and `|` as *non-short-circuiting* equivalents of `&&` and `||`,  but I can't imagine why you'd want to anyway.