# Why is the output different in case of &&, &, ||?

Tags: java, operators

Here is the code segments

Can you explain why outputs are varying

1)

```
public static ShortCkt {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean t = true;
        boolean f = false, b;
        b = (t && ((i++) == 0));
        b = (f && ((i+=2) > 0));
        System.out.println(i);      
    }
}
```

output in this case is 1

2)

```
public static ShortCkt {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean t = true;
        boolean f = false, b;
        b = (t & ((i++) == 0));
        b = (f & ((i+=2) > 0));
        System.out.println(i);      
    }
}
```

output in this case is 3

3)

```
public static ShortCkt {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean t = true;
        boolean f = false, b;
        b = (t || ((i++) == 0));
        b = (f || ((i+=2) > 0));
        System.out.println(i);      
    }
}
```

output in this case is 2

4)

```
public static ShortCkt {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean t = true;
        boolean f = false, b;
        b = (t | ((i++) == 0));
        b = (f | ((i+=2) > 0));
        System.out.println(i);      
    }
}
```

output in this case is 3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is the output different in case of &&, &, || ?

Just as in C/C++ `&&` is evaluated "lazily" while `&` is not.

If `a` is false then `a && b` will return false without even evaluating `b`.

Same goes for `a || b`: If the first operand, `a` is true, the whole expression is true and the second operand, `b` is never evaluated. For `a | b` however, both `a` and `b` will be evaluated.

This has consequences if the operand that's not being evaluated when using `&&` (or `||`) has side effects, as in your examples.

---

Side note: Few java-programmers know that `^` (xor) works for booleans as well. (A `^^` version does not exist simply because it would be redundant.)

Answer (score 7):

There are 4 `boolean` binary operators that we're concerned with here:

- `&&` is the conditional and operator

  - `&` is the logical and operator
- `||` is the conditional or operator

  - `|` is the logical or operator

Here's the key point:

- "conditional" means it short-circuits: it does not evaluate the right operand if it will not affect the result of the operation
- "logical" does not short-circuit: it evaluates both operands, left first, then right.
- The result of "and" is `true` only if both operands are `true`

  - If the left operand is `false`, the result is `false` regardless of right operand
- The result of "or" is `true` only if at least one operand is `true`

  - If the left operand is `true`, the result is `true` regardless of right operand

In other words, assuming no exception etc:

- `&` and `|` *always* evaluate both operands
- `&&` and `||` evaluate the right operand *conditionally*; the right operand is evaluated only if its value could affect the result of the binary operation. That means that the right operand is NOT evaluated when:

  - The left operand of `&&` evaluates to `false`

    - (because no matter what the right operand evaluates to, the entire expression is `false`)
  - The left operand of `||` evaluates to `true`

    - (because no matter what the right operand evaluates to, the entire expression is `true`)

#### References

- [JLS 15.22.2 Boolean Logical Operators `&`, `^`, and `|`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2)

  - For `&`, the result value is `true` if both operand values are `true`; otherwise, the result is `false`.
  - For `|`, the result value is `false` if both operand values are `false`; otherwise, the result is `true`.
- [JLS 15.23 Conditional-And Operator `&&`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23)

  - The `&&` operator is like `&`, but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is `true`.
- [JLS 15.24 15.24 Conditional-Or Operator `||`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.24)

  - The `||` operator is like `|`, but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is `false`.

#### See also

- [JLS 15.22.1 Integer Bitwise Operators `&`, `^`, and `|`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.1)

#### Related questions

- [What’s the difference between `|` and `||` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96667/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-java)
- [Do `&=` and `|=` short-circuit in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152208/do-and-short-circuit-in-java) (NO!)
- [Shortcut "or-assignment" (`|=`) operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486472/shortcut-or-assignment-operator-in-java)
- [Why doesn’t Java have `&&=` or `||=`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324549/why-doesnt-java-have-compound-assignment-versions-of-the-conditional-and-and-con)

Answer (score 1):

`&&` and `||` are the logical AND and OR operators, they always result in a `boolean` expression.  `&` and `|` are bitwise AND and OR operators, they do a bitwise comparison of each side.  For more information about what those operators do, see [this link](http://www.oopic.com/and.htm)

Comment: `&` and `|` can be `boolean` too. But no the DV wasn't me.

Comment: @poly Good point - I didn't specify a resulting type for `&` and `|` for this reason as I did with logical operators.  I should have explicitly stated that though.

Answer (score 1):

This is because && and || are logical operators which a "short circut mechanism". If you use || and the first expression evaluates to true, the second won't be evaluated and hence i will not be udated. & and | are bitwise operators which do bit calculations on the input. These do not have short circut and hence the entire expression is evaluated no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` and `|` operators are bitwise, and thus must have both sides of the expression evaluated before the operator can be used, so in cases 2 and 4 both sides of the operator are *always* evaluated.

The difference between cases 1 and 3 is based on short-circuit logic.

In case 1 the `&&` operator in the second expression short-circuits as `false` on the first `false`, causing the second half of the expression not to be evaluated.

In case 3 the `false` in the first half of the second expression leads to the evaluation of the second half of the expression, incrementing `i`.  `false || expr` can only be `false` if `expr` is also false (so it must be evaluated).