# Javascript: what's difference between | and ||?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some Javascript code that is:

```
if ( a>2 | b>4 ) { ... }
```

(ignore the ... above).  What's the | doing? I assume it's logical OR, but all the references I could find online speak about ||, and I can't find anything mentioning just |. Thanks in advance

Comment: See the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439951/why-is-the-output-different-in-case-of

Comment: The same as in most other programming languages ;)

Comment: Imo you should accept @aaronasterling's answer as it actually describes how `|` works. My answer is merely an extended comment ;)

Comment: While it's not present in any of the answers below... `|` *always* evaluates both arguments, where as `||` (and `&&`) are *short-circuit* operators and only evaluate as much as needed. e.g. `var res = true || thisIsNeverExecuted()` -- `||` (and `&&`) are usually [always] correct for dealing with logic, but sometimes (and very questionably so!), the short-circuit behavior is not wanted. Some people use `|` or `&` to get about this in a pinch. I'd argue for maintainable code instead though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `||` and `|` is already explained in the other answers.

However, in the above code, `|` has the same effect as `||` due to type conversion.

`true` and `false` are mapped to `1` and `0` and we have

```
0 | 0 = 0
1 | 0 = 1
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

The same goes into the other direction, `1` evaluates to `true` and `0` to `false`.

So in this example,

```
if ( a>2 | b>4 )
```

will have the same result as

```
if ( a>2 || b>4 )
```

**Note:** This really only works with the two values `0` and `1`.

---

<del>This could be some kind of micro-optimization.</del>

**Update:**

However, a short test reveals that using the bitwise OR for this purpose is **way slower** (at least in Chrome 9):

http://jsperf.com/js-or-test

**Conclusion:** Don't use it instead of logical OR :) Mostly likely someone forgot the second `|` and is just lucky that the code produces the same result.

Use boolean operators for boolean operations and bitwise operators for fancy bit masking. This might be worth reading: [MDC - Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Comment: It is also important to note that || shortcircuits, | does not.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that this is a micro-optimization and not simply somebody not knowing the difference between the two. `||` can short circuit and doesn't require coercion. Neither of the two is true for `|`.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Yes, using `|` is indeed an order of magnitud slower.

Answer (score 4):

It's the bitwise or. `||` is logical or.

The bitwise or (`|`) coerces the values to 32 bit integers and returns the 32 bit integer with each bit set to 1 if either of the two bits in the corresponding locations is 1 and 0 if they are both 0.

Logical or (`||`) evaluates to the first value if it's not falsey, otherwise it evaluates to the second value.

You almost definitely want `||` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 2):

Single | is a bitwise-OR while double (||) is a logical-OR.

Bitwise-OR takes the binary representation of the two source values and ORs them together so that if either of the values has a bit set, the resulting value's bit will also be set (repeat for all the bits in the two source values).

Logical-OR concerns itself with true and false values (where 0 maps to false and non-zero maps to true - that's simplified, JavaScript has more specific rules). If either source value is true then the result is true.

Comment: That is not true in JavaScript. The **value** of an overall "||" expression is the value of either the left side or the right side, depending on which of the two is not **falsy**.  The left side is evaluated first, and if it's not **falsy** then that's the value of the "||"" expression. Otherwise the value is that of the right side. The distinction is that unlike, say, Java, the **type** of the result is not necessarily boolean - it can be **any** type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like second pipe just got lost, otherwise it is a smelly hack. See what really happens:

```
if ( Boolean( Number(a>2) | Number(b>4) ) ) { ... }
```

(`Number` is special here because bitwise operators are working with 32-bit integers)
 It works because Number(true) === 1 && Number(false) === 0.