# Bitwise operator and single ampersand

Tags: java, operators, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why do we usually use `||` not `|`, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference)

Can I use single ampersand like `&` instead of a bitwise operator like `&&`?  What kind of differences may arise and is there a specific example to illustrate this issue clearly?

Comment: this may sound a little like nitpicking, but the other question asks for a/the reason of a/the dominant coding variant, while this one is a little "broader"; Hot Licks' answer (2nd one) would be (more) inappropriate if given as a answer for the question "Why do we usually use || not |, what is the difference?" while it provides for (in my opinion) valuable additional insight here

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The single `&` will check both conditions always. The double `&&` will stop after the first condition if it evaluates to false. Using two is a way of "short circuiting" the condition check if you truly only need 1 condition of 2 to be true or false.

An example could be:

```
if (myString != null && myString.equals("testing"))
```

If `myString` is `null`, the first condition would fail and it would not bother to check the value of it. This is one way you can avoid null pointers.

- with `&` and `¦` both operands are always evaluated
- with `&&` and `¦¦` the second operand is only evaluated when it is necessary

Here's a link to a page with a pretty good explanation of how to use these.

[Java Quick Reference on Operators](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/and-operators-and-in-java.html)

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Use "&", "|" and friends if you want to twiddle bits (e.g. for bitmapped flags).  Use "&&" or "||" if you want to evaluate "if this, then that" conditionals.  An important consideration using the latter is "short circuit evaluation", meaning evaluation will STOP the moment it encounters a definite "true" or "false".

Comment: Link now points to Spam

Comment: I updated the link to use another site now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 22):

The other answers are correct to an extent, but don't explain the whole thing.

First off, the doubled operators, `&&` and `||`, function sort of like nested `if` statements:

```
if (expression_a && expression_b) {
    do_something;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (expression_a) {
    if (expression_b) {
        do_something;
    }
}
```

In both cases, if `expression_a` evaluates to `false` then `expression_b` will not be evaluated -- a feature referred to as "short-circuiting".  (The `||` case is similar but a hair more complicated.)

Additionally, in Java (but not in C/C++) the `&&` and `||` operators apply *only* to boolean values -- you cannot use `&&` or `||` on an `int`, eg.

The single operators, `&` and `|`, on the other hand, are relatively "pure" operators (commutative and associative with respect to themselves), with none of the "short-circuiting" of the double operators.  Additionally, they can operate on any integer type -- boolean, char, byte, short, int, long.  They perform a bit-by-bit operation -- bit N of the left operand is ANDed or ORed with bit N of the right operand to produce the Nth bit in a result value that is the same bit width as the two operands (after they are widened as appropriate for binary operators).  In this regard, their operation with `boolean` is just the degenerate case (albeit one that is somewhat special-cased).

Normally, one would use only the doubled operators for combining boolean expressions in an `if` statement.  There is no great harm in using the single operators if the boolean expressions involved are "safe" (cannot result in a null pointer exception, eg), but the doubled operators tend to be slightly more efficient and the short-circuiting is often desired (as in `if (a != null && a.b == 5)`, eg), so it's generally wise to cultivate the habit of using the doubled forms.  The only thing to beware of is that if you *want* the second expression to be evaluated (for it's side-effects), the doubled operator will not guarantee this happens.

Comment: Nice explanation on why single operator form works for boolean expression, helped me understand.