# What does the ampersand do in a print statement?

Tags: printing, ampersand, operand

**&** = Check both statements.
**&&** = Check one statement.

I understand the use of the ampersand as an operand but I have no idea how or why it would be used in a print statement.

Take Java for example:

```
System.out.println(10 & 7);
```

This outputs 2. Why does this output 2?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691693/bitwise-operator-and-single-ampersand will help

Comment: I know the use of & in an IF statement. How does it work in a print statement? I really have no idea why 2 would be the result of 10 and 7.

Comment: the single ampersand is doing a "bitwise and" see this answer for an example - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7199886/2766872

Comment: That answers it, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome.  not sure how a question like this will ever get closed though - as I didn't provide an answer - and the answer is not on this thread...

Comment: Why not put the information from your comments into an answer, so it can be upvoted and accepted?