# Is following true in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is following true in java:

In java if you use `||` then after getting first true condition it neglects the rest conditions. That is If you write `if(a || b || c)` in java and java finds `a` is true then it will not check for `b` and `c`, just go into the if case.

Comment: Yes, its true. | and & are also bitwise operators

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is called short circuiting, if you put less expensive checks to the left you might avoid the expensive ones to follow.

This works for `||` and `&&`

one of the best uses is checking a value from an object that might be null:

```
if(myList != null && myList.size() > 6)
```

the previous line is null safe, reversing the condition will cause a null pointer exception in case myList is null

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. `||` is called short-circuit `OR` evaluation, or an *OR-ELSE* operator.

This is important in situations when evaluating the right-hand side may cause an undesirable consequence:

```
 if (myString == null || myString.indexOf("hello") != -1)
      ...
```

would crash if it were not for short-circuiting.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, This way the compiler avoids unnecessary checking and calculation overhead.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, and that's not just laziness on part of the language implementation, but rather it is a crucial feature - short-circuiting allows you to write something like this:

```
if (myarray.length > 10 && myarray[10] == 5) { /* ... */ }
```

Here the second condition may only even be *evaluated* if the first one is true. Thanks to short-circuiting, if the first condition is false the second is never touched.

Answer (score 0):

### YES

(AFAIK)
The same things applies to `&&` but in reverse manner.(for first false).

---

The same rule as in circuits for AND and OR gates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called [short-circuiting](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=65). It also will short circuit `&&`, i.e.

```
 if (a && b && c)
```

If `a` is `false` then the condition cannot be true, neither `b` nor `c` are checked.

This can be problematic if you call methods that return booleans. To get around this, you can use bitwise `&` and `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct. If you use | this operator to check OR condition then it checks rest all conditions. It also applied on AND(&) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and one **important thing**, if you do any operations in the second part, they will not be made. For example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
if ( a == b  || a++ == b){
    ...
}
//a = 5
//b = 5
```

BUT in case:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 5;
if ( a == b  || a++ == b){
    ...
}
//a = 4
//b = 5
```

I tried to make a simple example, but sometimes you call a method in the second part, (which will not be called if first part was `true` in case of `||`), or the first part was `false` in case of `&&`