# If statement with && where the first condition needs to be true before testing the second

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't even think of a way to search of this. I'm not sure of the terminology to ask the question, so I'll just walk through my problem.

From my tests, it seems the if statement will quit before attempting to go to go to array[10]. I that always the case? Meaning, if I have an && in my if statement and the left side is false, will it always exit before testing the second? And for that matter, will it always test the left first?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean [] array = new boolean [10];
        Arrays.fill(array, true);
        int i = 10;
        if(i < array.length && array[i]){
            System.out.println("WhoHoo!");
        }
}
```

Comment: && is called short circuit operator. This is the reason behind it.

Comment: take a look a the answer for this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logcial-operators-short-circuiting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) on operators:

> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR
>   operations on two boolean expressions. These operators exhibit
>   "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is
>   evaluated only if needed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Java Tutorial and the correct terms

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If the left side is false, it will terminate the condition. Because if you put `&&` then all the conditions must be true, if anyone condition turns false, then there is no need to go further. So it terminates when the condition gets `false`

Answer (score 1):

> if I have an && in my if statement and the left side is false, will it
>   always exit before testing the second?

Yes. If the left side is false, there is no need to check the right side, because when you have:

```
if(a && b) { ... }
```

If `!a`, then the whole statement is evaluated to *false* no matter what `b` is.

If `a`, then it will continue to evaluate the next.

For summary, always remember [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html):

> ...the second operand is evaluated **only if needed**.

Comment: I just tested that, that doesn't seem to be the case. Are you sure? is my compiler just figuring out what I mean and doing some behind the scenes magic?

Comment: I would like to add this : if you still want to evaluate `b` (e.g. because it is a method that returns a boolean) you need to type `(a & b)`. Using a single ampersand will not short circuit your evaluation.

Comment: @Maroun I tried if((array.length < 10 && true) && array[i]) The program just terminated without throwing an array out of bounds exception

Comment: Made a dumb mistake. Corrected code: if((i < array.length && true) && array[i])

Comment: @Maroun c will not be evaluated in the case you describe.

Comment: @JamesFargotson `(i < array.length && true)` is evaluated to `false`, then there is no need to continue to `array[i]`. That's why it works.

Comment: @yiannis Thanks. Edited.. Definitely time to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

It will only evaluate second condition if first condition evaluates to **true**.

The evaluation starts from left and when it evaluates to false further evaluation does not happen.