# While loop stop at first false condition

Tags: java

I have this `while` loop:

```
//All of this code is inside a for loop
positionUp = i - 1;

while ((positionUp > 0) && boardMatrix[positionUp][j] == boardMatrix[i][j]) {

    //do something

    positionUp--;
}
```

At some point, it is possible that `positionUp` it's assigned with the value `-1` (when `i=0`)

I thought that the `while`loop will stop at the first `false`evaluation thus not evaluating `boardMatrix[positionUp][j]` and not getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

I'm not seeing how can I solve this. Can someone point me in the way?

Comment: Are you sure the exception thrown from here?

Comment: What is happening to j? Could that be set to -1 as well?

Comment: I too dint get exception

Comment: I try your code.
it's work fine....

Comment: I would suggest you to do a debug and ensure that your assumption is indeed correct.  I doubt that the error is coming due to some other reason (may be j or i has a wrong value) and not due to positionUp is -1

Comment: @All. The problem was with the j variable BEFORE entering the while loop. I've checked Only inside the while loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your loop (temporarily) to:

```
System.out.println ("pos="+positionUp+",i="+i+",j="+j);
while ((positionUp > 0) && boardMatrix[positionUp][j] == boardMatrix[i][j]) {
    positionUp--;
    System.out.println ("pos="+positionUp+",i="+i+",j="+j);
}
```

to see *which* variable is causing the problem. The Java logical operators *do* short-circuit so the problem most likely lies with the other variables, depending on how they change in the loop.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was with the `j` variable BEFORE  entering the while loop. I've checked Only inside the while loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your problem is: the while loop trys to resolve your condition. your condition contains an access to a array-index which not exists. so before your condition turns "false", an ArrayOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

to solve this you could go:

```
while ((positionUp > 0) && 
       null != boardMatrix &&
       null != boardMatrix[positionUp][j] && 
       null != boardMatrix[i][j] && 
       boardMatrix[positionUp][j] == boardMatrix[i][j]) {

    //do something

    positionUp--;
}
```

Comment: That will _still_ raise an exception by the way since you're still indexing an invalid position and _then_ comparing it to null for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Java does have short-circuit operators (&& and || - see [Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logcial-operators-short-circuiting)). So as long as positionUp is <= 0, the second part will not execute.

This strongly suggests the ArrayOutOfBoundsException originates in your i and j variables.

I would output them (before they are used in the array) so you can see what values they have when the exception is thrown.