# Condition evaluation process in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-construction, jvm, evaluation

Lets say I have the following condition:

```
if ( myList == null || myList.isEmpty() || xomeX == someY )
```

What is the order of the evaluation of these conditions? Left or right, right to left or random **each** time?

If the first one passes, then the others are ignored?

Comment: Left to right i guess :) yes other will be ignored

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It should be always be *left to right* except the assignment operator `=` . You are using short circuit `OR` operator , hence if the first condition is `true` , rest of them won't be evaluated.

[JLS 15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24):

> The conditional-or operator is syntactically left-associative (it groups left-to-right).
>
> At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; if the result has type Boolean, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> If the resulting value is true, the value of the conditional-or expression is true and the right-hand operand expression is not evaluated.

Comment: "except the assignment operator `=`". The left operand of the assignment operator is evaluated before the right operand as well.

Comment: @sepp2k How this should be evaluated : `x=y=z+1;` !

Comment: First `x` is evaluated, then `y`, then `z`, then `1`, then `valueOfZ  +1`, then `y = resultOfZPlus1`, then `x = resultOfAssigningY`.

Answer (score 7):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)

> At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first [...] If the resulting value is true, the value of the conditional-or expression is true and the right-hand operand expression is not evaluated.

Comment: Associativity is irrelevant to the order in which the operands are evaluated.

Comment: @sepp2k You're right, I better remove that part

Answer (score 7):

```
if ( myList == null || myList.isEmpty() || xomeX == someY )
```

**Yes the evaluation is from left to right!**

and

If the first condition is true next condition is not evaluated. This concept is called Short-circuit evaluation. You can read more on this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Similar SO question posted earlier is [Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logcial-operators-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 3):

1) left to right

2) in this case, if one condition is true, it doesn't evaluate the rest. so if `myList` is null, it won't throw a `NullPointerException` evaluating `myList.isEmpty()` (because it won't evaluate it)

Answer (score 1):

Every operator has its own [precedence](http://thinkingjava.blogspot.com/2006/02/precedence-and-associativity-rules-for.html) and [associativity](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-assoc.html).

These links are enough to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

|| is the short-circuit OR operator, that means that conditions are strictly evaluated from left to right, and this checking process stops on first true result.