# Are all booleans in a OR conditional evaluated in Java?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Ok so I had a weird issue in java and I'm pretty sure this is common to most languages but it was the first time I've encountered something like this. Assume you have two methods.

```
private boolean foo(int param){ /*some arbitrary stuff*/ }
private boolean bar(int param){ /*some arbitrary stuff*/ }
```

Each of these methods expect parameters and based on the contents of the parameters they return a `true` or `false` based on whether or not something happened. Now I'm going to put them to work.

```
if(foo(21) || bar(321)){

    //do some other stuff

}
```

The idea here is to run `foo()` and `bar()` and if either of them return `true` do the other stuff.

It looked fine, it compiled, but when I ran the code things were funky. It was almost as if `bar()` was not running whenever `foo()` returned `true`. So realizing the logical possibility of that I rewrote my code.

```
boolean a = foo(21);
boolean b = bar(321);

if(a || b){

    //do some other stuff

}
```

and that fixed my issue. My question is does anyone know why this happens or if there are other practices to ensure the entirety of a conditional is evaluated should it need to?

Comment: This a good example of why it is good to avoid side-effects in expressions :) Note than you can use `bool | bool`, which does not short-circuit. But see above.

Comment: The reason it's important to have operators like `||` is that so you can write stuff like `if (index >= myArray.length ||  myArray[index] == 0)`.  If the right part were always evaluated, even if the index were too large, you couldn't do this--it would get an out-of-bounds exception, even though we already know from the left part that the whole expression will be `true`.  (I used to program in Pascal, which doesn't have short circuits, and it's really a pain to work around.)  It's not just array indexes.  There are **lots** of uses.

Comment: @ajb Yeah upon learning about this right now I've already cut out maybe 16 lines of code from just one of my classes. This has been a very enlightening discovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with short-circuiting. Using `||` causes the operation to short-circuit once one true value is found. You can instead use `|` to evaluate both expressions, even if the first is true. Same is true with `&&` and `&` when it comes to evaluating to false.

```
if (true || someMethod()) { }
```

In this statement above, the someMethod() will never be called because `true` short-circuits the result.

```
if (true | someMethod()) { }
```

In this, the someMethod() will be called even though it being true or false is irrelevant to the evaluation of the boolean expression as a whole. See here for more information on short-circuiting in Java: [Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Comment: Excellent answer and thanks for all of the extra information! I can't believe this is the first time I've ever encountered this. I'll accept this answer when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

This is called *short-circuiting*.

Logical operators will stop evaluating their operands once they know what the result will be.