# Why does this boolean expression not work flipped?

Tags: java

This is what I wrote for a coding bat project thing. For some reason it says that this way it doesn't work but if I flip it, it works. Why is that? When it inputs something with less than 3 chars it gets an error message according to codingbat.

```
// Given a string, return a new string where "not " has been added to the front. 
// However, if the string already begins with "not", return the string unchanged. 
// Note: use .equals() to compare 2 strings. 

// notString("candy") → "not candy"
// notString("x") → "not x"
// notString("not bad") → "not bad"

        public String notString(String str) {
                  String m;
          if ( str.substring (0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("not") && str.length () >= 3 ) // this line doesn't work in it's current state 
          // but works if I flip the two boolean expressions over the &&

                    m = str;
          else {
                    m = "not " + str;
                }
       return m;
```

Comment: Because you are first getting `substring` and then checking its `length`. What would happen if `length` is less than 3. First part of `&&` would result in error. My guess is it is compiler's way of handling this scenario.

Comment: Instead of using `str.substring (0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("not")` you could use `str.startsWith("not")` and if we want to ignore the case you wound add `str.toLowerCase().startsWith("not")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the length of the string is not at least 3, then `str.subtring(0, 3)` will fail with a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The reason that it works when flipped is called *short circuit evaluation*.  Flipped:

```
if ( str.length() >= 3 && str.substring (0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("not") )
```

The first condition is evaluated.  If it's less than 3, then Java knows that the whole condition is `false`, because `false && anything` is `false`.  It won't evaluate the other expression, because it doesn't have to evaluate it.  The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` doesn't come for this reason.

The [JLS, Section 15.23](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) talks about this:

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates
>   its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is
>   true.

Additionally, the logical-or operator (conditional-or operator) `||` works similarly.  It will only evaluate its right-side operand if the left-side operand is `false` ([JLS Section 15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)).

Comment: Wow, ok now I get it. Thanks to everyone who contributed on this question!

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted above will crash with a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `str` is shorter than three characters, because you're trying to take a 3-character `substring` of a string that's not long enough.

However, when you flip it around, you check the length of the string *first*. This means that you know right away that the `&&` will fail (because `str.length >= 3` is `false`), so you [short-circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/2069350) out of the conditional right then and there. As a result, you never try to take the impossible `substring`, and you avoid the crash.

As mentioned in the link, *both* of the logical operators work this way (`&&` (AND) and `||` (OR)). If they're able to figure out what to return after evaluating only the left-hand side, the right-hand side never gets touched. So, for example, `(true || 1/0 == 0)` will always evaluate to `true`, even though if the right-hand side were to be evaluated, it would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you check

```
str.substring (0,3).equalsIgnoreCase("not")
```

first, before checking a length. So you propably gen an error `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if your str is of length less than 3.

You have to check a length first (e.g. by flipping conditions check).