# The difference between && and ||

Tags: java

Im not understanding the difference between the && and the || in a certain regard.

```
If(a && b) { then do this }
```

Now if a is false then b ***Is*** looked at, but the condition is not tested.

But....

```
If(a || b) { then do this }
```

Now, if a is true then b ***Is not*** looked at, and the condition is not tested.

Why is this. I thought the purpose of the && and the || was to sort of a help speed things along. If it could determine a result by testing the first condition, it wouldnt need look at the second condition. But in the case of && it does look at it. While in the case of || it dosent.

Do i have this right?
If i do, why is this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Comment: "Now if a is false then b **Is** looked at, but the condition is not tested."  How exactly did you determine this to be true?

Comment: See the duplicate, and read about Truth Tables for logical conjunction (&&) and logical disjunction (||) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction)

Answer (score 13):

To understand the answer, remind yourself of the truth tables of `AND` and `OR` operations:

```
  AND  true   | false
     \--------+-------
true  | true  | false
------+-------+-------
false | false | false


   OR  true   | false
     \--------+-------
true  | true  | true
------+-------+-------
false | true  | false
```

Note the second column for `AND` and the first column for `OR`: they have identical values. This is the key to understanding the reason why `AND` ignores its second argument when the first evaluates to `false`: that's when the second argument does not matter (the second column). The opposite is true for the `OR` operator: now a `false` in the first argument means that the second one does matter. However, a `true` in the first argument (the first column) means that the second argument can be ignored.

> I thought the purpose of the && and the || was to sort of a help speed things along.

That's a smaller part of their purpose. Much bigger one is protection of right side of an expression based on its left side. Consider a situation where you want to guard against empty and `null` strings. If `&&` and `||` didn't "short circuit" the evaluation, you would be forced to write code like this:

```
if (s == null) return false;
if (s.length() == 0) return false;
```

The reason you can write

```
if (s == null || s.length() == 0) return false;
```

is the short circuiting: there is a guarantee that `s.length()` would not be invoked on a `null` string.

Answer (score 5):

`&&` is used to perform `and` operation means if anyone of the `expression/condition` evaluates to false whole thing is false.

```
so if any one of the condition becomes false it won't even continue further to check
```

`||` is used to perform `or` operation if anyone of the  `expression/condition` evaluates to true whole thing becomes true.

```
so it continues till the end to check atleast one condition to become true.
```

Comment: uhm... read his question again carefully.

Comment: This is **not* what OP asked about.

Comment: I understand this. But in the case of && the 2nd condition is looked at regardless of whether the first condition is true or false. Why?

Comment: Ok. My teacher has mislead me. Setting a condition to false as in (a=false) had me thinking this condition is true because "a" can accept false. Im a student, and my teachers are non university educated. Im sorry, this has all been a mistake.

Comment: @ragingbull: The best thing might be to delete the question so it doesn't lead to further confusion.

Answer (score 2):

`&& is AND where as || is OR operator.` && looks for false, means if first argument false, it wont test second whether it is true or false.
 || looks for true, means even though first argument false, it test for second. If both are false then false otherwise true. In && case both are true then true otherwise false.

Comment: Read again the question. It's not that simple.

Answer (score 2):

`a && b` can't be true if a is false, so if a really is false, there's no need to examine b.

`a || b` can't be false if a is true, so if a really is true, there's no need to examine b.

They're called short-circuit operators for that reason.

If you're trying to defeat that behavior, use & and | instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... On the off chance the question is your confusion regarding the && operator evaluating the right-hand operand when the left-hand operand is false, then read this:

[Conditional And Operator (Java Language Specification)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23)

Specifically, the first sentence:

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates
>   its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is
>   true.

and the last:

> Thus, && computes the same result as & on boolean operands. It differs
>   only in that the right-hand operand expression is evaluated
>   conditionally rather than always.