# My code is supposed to take in a number, and return either the letter grade or "Grade is not valid" but the else statement is not working

Tags: c++

My code is supposed to take in a number, and return either the letter grade or "Grade is not valid" but the else statement is not working.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int score = 0;
    string response  = "Grade is ";
    cout<<"Please enter score: "<<endl;
    cin>>score;
    if(score<100 || score>0){
        if (score>=0 && score<60)
            cout<<response<<"F"<<endl;
        if(score>=60 && score<70)
            cout<<response<<"D"<<endl;
        if(score>=70 && score<80)
            cout<<response<<"C"<<endl;
        if(score>=80 && score<90)
            cout<<response<<"B"<<endl;
        if (score>=90 && score<100)
            cout<<response<<"A"<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"Not a valid score"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Lets say the score is `-1`, what is the result of `score<100 || score>0`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207997/the-difference-between-and

Comment: " is not working" is not a valid description of your problem

Comment: Just switch `score<100 || score>0` to `score <= 100 && score >=0` and `score>=90 && score<100` to `score>=90 && score<=100`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. The score should be greater than or equal to 0 AND less than or equal to 100, not OR.