# Java OR operator precedence

Tags: java, operator-precedence

How to chain conditional statements in Java in a way that if `b` is false, than do not check `c`?

If `a` and `c` are false, and `b` is true, does `c` will be checked?

```
if (a || b || c)
```

I am looking for similar feature that PHP holds with difference between `OR` and `||`

Comment: No, || does short circuit evaluation. So if a is false, b will be checked and if b is true, c won't be checked. If you're not sure, you can always test : http://ideone.com/mCE8hy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Java `||` operator (logical or operator) does not evaluate additional arguments if the left operand is `true`. If you wanted to do that, you can use `|` (bitwise or operator), although, according to the name, this is a little of a hack.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23

> Thus, && computes the same result as & on boolean operands. It differs only in that the right-hand operand expression is evaluated conditionally rather than always.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24

> Thus, || computes the same result as | on boolean or Boolean operands. It differs only in that the right-hand operand expression is evaluated conditionally rather than always.

Extra: it is considered bad programming style to depend on these semantics to conditionally call code with side effects.

Comment: Sometimes it's needed if you want to squeeze performance out of your program

Comment: ah, I thought you were talking about `if(isAlright || doSomething()) ...` and not about `if(firstCondition || expensiveSecondCondition()) ...`. The first is a method with side effects, the second is just an expensive function without side effect. I'd say that the second one is fine anyway.

Comment: Still it's shady and not readable-frendly but still sometimes you just have to meet the specs ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`c` won't be checked. To prove this, you can use the following code:

```
boolean a() {
  System.out.println("a")
  return false;
}

boolean b() {
  System.out.println("b")
  return true;
}

boolean c() {
  System.out.println("c")
  return true;
}

void test() {
  if(a() || b() || c()) {
    System.out.println("done")
  }
}
```

The output will be:

```
a
b
done
```

Answer (score 1):

if (a || b || c)

for you case,

a is true then b and c not checked.

a is false and b is true then c not checked.

a and b are false then c is checked.

the left side of the operator is evaluated first

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is false and `b` is true, then `c` will not be evaluated.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/892168) that addresses short circuiting of logical operators in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How to chain conditional statements in Java in a way that if **b** is false, than do not check **c**?

- Why do you need that?? it kills OR logic - neways `c` then is immaterial
- so your answer simply is `if (a || b)`
- or may be you are looking for `if (a || (b && c))`

> 2) If a and c are false, and b is true, does c will be checked?  [ if (a || b || c) ]

- Nope
- `||` does short circuit evaluation. So if `a` is `false`, `b` will be checked and if `b` is true, `c` won't be checked

For more on short circuit evaluation: [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)