# Printing out a string only if it contains at least one character question confusion

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

There is this question that I am stuck on:

The answer is Version 3 but I am unsure why. I tried testing it with a test string assigned null, heres version 2 I used:

```
String str = null;
if (str != null || !str.equals("")){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

And it was giving me a null pointer exception for all versions except version 3 which I am really confused about.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "And it was giving me a null pointer exception for all versions except version 3 which I am really confused about." Well, do you know what a null pointer exception is? Do you know how `&&` and `||` work? Is it permissible to call a method on `null`? If the code has a method call on the *left* hand side of `&&` or `||`, will that call be attempted? Knowing those things, try to prove to me that the other versions of the code should work. (You cannot, because they do not; but the attempt should make it clear why they do not.)

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to talk through the code yourself; and read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. "I am confused about this" is not a question at all, let alone one appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: (If you *don't* know the answers to the questions in my first comment, you should review your textbook first, or talk to your instructor, or [try to find answers yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+what+is+null+pointer+exception).)

Comment: @jhanzaib said it all. these two questions could help also in your exercise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263660/in-java-what-are-the-boolean-order-of-operations and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202415/java-or-operator-precedence

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

If you do any operation on a null String, it gives null pointer exception. `( Here you are comparing it with !str.equals(""))`

Another point to note is :
in || condition , if first condition is true, the second wont be evaluated.

whereas in && , if the first condition is false , the second condition is not evaluated.

For this reason,
Both of these are called short circuit operators.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the second condition will be checked regardless of the outcome of the first condition in || like @Jhanzaib Humayun said

Comment: @rhian, no i've replied to his comment

Comment: the version2 mentioned in the pic and the one typed by you, in that, condition in if are reversed ( first becomes second and vice versa0)

Answer (score 1):

The conditions in your `if`-statements have to be checked. So, if you have `str != null || !str.equals("")` in your `if`-statement, then you will check `str != null` and then check `!str.equals("")` if the first statement is `false`. Let's say that the string is `null`. The first condition is `false` and the second condition tries to check `!str.equals("")`. Then you get a NullPointerException, because you can't compare `null` to a string.

However, if you use `str != null && !str.equals("")`, then `str != null` will be checked first and the second statement `!str.equals("")` will only be checked if the first one is `true`. Meaning, the code will never get to `!str.equals("")` if the string is `null`. So, you never get the NullPointerException.

You can't use `str.equals("")` because `null` doesn't have an equals method. By using `==` you check the reference of your string. Everything that is `null` has the same reference, so if your string is `null`, then it will point to the `null` reference, and `==` can be used to check that refernce.

Comment: Great explanation thank you. Just to confirm a string can be checked against str != null but a null string cannot be checked against !str.equals("") ?

Comment: ". So, if you have str != null || !str.equals("") in your if-statement, then you will check str != null and then check !str.equals("") regardless of the outcome of the first condition since you are using ||, which means "or""
- this is wrong.  ( if first condition is true, second wont be evaluated )

Comment: Added an explanation for ` !str.equals("")`. @Gurkirat thanks for the correction.