# java switch statement many cases simplified

Tags: java, switch-statement

So lets say a switch statment is,

```
switch (month) {  
    case 1: monthString = "January";  
        break;  
    case 2: monthString = "February";  
        break;  
    case 3: monthString = "March";  
        break;  
    case 4: monthString = "April";  
        break;  
    case 5: monthString = "May";  
        break;
```

Is it possible to shorten that to something like

```
switch (month) {
    cases 1-3: monthString = "January";
        break;
    case 4-5: monthString = "April";
        break;
```

So that multiple case numbers are under one case? I'm doing it as I have 100 cases. 30 lead to one answer, 20 to another, 5 to another etc... so if I can use multiple cases I should cut down the bulk of the code by alot. I should also mention at each case I will want to do a few things and if I use a series of if else statements it only lets me perform one action so I cannot seem to go that route. Thanks for any help! sorry I'm new at this!

Comment: You can use case statements like -- case 1: case 2: case 3: -- etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to shorten that to something like

It's better explained in *Java Tutorial* [The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Yes you can do it.

Some of the key points:

- Don't forget to add the `break` statement.
- Add single `break` statement after all grouped cases.
- Never forget to add `default` case as well.

sample code:

```
    int month = 1;
    String monthString = null;

    switch (month) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            monthString = "January";
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
            monthString = "April";
            break;
        ...
        default:
            ...
    }
```

Comment: When doing something like this you should leave a comment in the code that this was intended.

Comment: What do you mean? Does intend change the logic of the program?

Comment: As part of my job I maintain code. There is no documentation, all I can do is read and run it.  If you use fall through cases, there are two reasons - it is intentional or it was a mistake.  I ran into such a problem. It is just a comment, like //intentional

Answer (score 2):

You might consider an array.

```
static String[] MONTHS = ",January,January,January,April,April".split(",");

monthString = MONTHS[month];
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing it as I have 100 cases. 30 lead to one answer, 20 to another, 5 to another etc

based on that why not compare size of the int instead of using a lot of fall-through cases. 
No matter what you do 100 cases, will still be a lot of tedious code to write but i can't imagine any one doing 30 fall through cases or 20 fall through case. Since your comparing `int` not `String` you can go with if statements like so:

```
 if (month > 0 && month <= 30) {
    monthString = "January";
 }

 else if (month > 30 && month <= 50) {
    monthString = "February";
 }

 else if (month > 50 && month <= 55) {
    monthString = "March";
 }

 // 55 cases have been matched
```

compared to:

```
switch (month) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    ...
    case 28:
    case 29:
    case 30:
        monthString = "January";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then yes. But it's not

```
switch (month) {
cases 1-3: monthString = "January";
    break;
case 4-5: monthString = "April";
    break;
}
```

It would be

```
switch (month) {
cases 1: case 2: case 3: monthString = "January";
    break;
case 4: case 5: monthString = "April";
    break;
}
```

Case statements fall through without a `break`. Also, you may want a `default:` it's like an `else` if your number might be outside any explicit case.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

```
switch (month) {  
    case 1: 

    case 2:   

    case 3:  monthString = "January";   
        break;  
    case 4: 

    case 5:  
        monthString = "April";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if-else. It will be easier for this scenario.

Comment: Nice alternative, I agree with Charles.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hashmap:

HashMap mySet = new HashMap()

and then fill it with the appropriate sets:

(new Integer(1), "January")

(new Integer(2), "January")

(new Integer(3), "January")

(new Integer(4), "April")

(new Integer(5), "April")

then your code looks like:

```
monthString = null;
mySet.containsKey(new Integer(month)) && monthString = mySet.getValue(new Integer(month))
```

That way you're taking advantage of short circuiting and having

```
"monthString = mySet.getValue(new Integer(month))"
```

only execute if that key is in the set. You can also make a function which populates your HashMap, thereby making it easy to maintain.

You can read up more on short-circuiting in java here:
[Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (month) {

  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  monthString = "January";
    break;
  case 4:
  case 5:
  monthString = "April";
    break;
}
```

You can use this and split function given by @Peter  works great.