# In a instance like this why the both conditions are not cheked

Tags: java

```
class A
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  int z=5;
  if(++z>5||++z>6)
  {
   z++;
  }
  System.out.println(z);
 }
}
```

Comment: Because if condition1 is true then `consition1 || condition2` will always be true.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `OR` logical operator,both conditions don't have to be `true`.If the first condition is true it will execute the statement
without checking the second condition.If you want to check both conditions,use `AND` logic

Comment: Answering bad questions does not contribute to the site.

Comment: ok thank you your comment was helpful

Comment: people asking questions because they don't know the answer ,"immibis ".You may be a pro.but there are student that still studying.so help them to learn.

Comment: thanks ,thank you sir Malakhi_Elohim

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the [short-circuit operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting) in this case it is `OR`

In which, once first condition is is true it whole experssion gets evaulated to true and hence no need to run second condition

Answer (score 0):

This is due to **Short-Circuit Logical Operators**

- The OR operator results in true when one operand is true, no matter
  what the second operand is.
- The AND operator results in false when one operand is false, no
  matter what the second operand is.
- If you use the || and &&, Java will not evaluate the right-hand
  operand when the outcome can be determined by the left operand alone.

Since in your case as **1st condition** evaluates to be true So **2nd condition** will not executed

```
class A
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  int z=5;
  if(++z>5||++z>6)//Condition 1 is true so the final result is true
  {
   z++;
  }
  System.out.println(z);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix you problem

```
 class A {

       public static void main(String args[]) {

         int z=5;
         if(++z>5 && ++z>6) { //Short-Circuit AND

             z++;
          }

          System.out.println(z);

        }
    }
```