# The order to check the conditions

Tags: java

So i have

`if(A != null && (A.getFullName() == null || A.getFirstName().equals("")){}`

Does the jvm check `A.getFullName` first before checking `A.getFirstName`? Is the order from left to right or could it check `A.getFirstName` before `A.getFullName`? I am asking because if `A.getFullName` is `null`, `A.getFirstName` will give me a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Are you Trying to compare String values?

Comment: Java strings are double quotes and you're missing a parenthesis.

Comment: Object like string need .equals(object). Also you will get a runtime exeption as JVM doesn't process it as you say left to right you need to check beforehand.

Comment: Well, yes, the left hand operand of `||` is always evaluated before the right hand operand; moreover the right hand operator won't be evaluated if the left hand operand comes out true.  But you need some parentheses to call a method - like `getFullName()`, and you need to use `equals()` to compare strings, not `==`.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am comparing with .equals. Edited the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Java's logical operator do [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). In your case this means that if `A.getFullName()` returns `null`, `A.getFirstName()` will not be called.

See [Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting) for further discussion.

Comment: The question was edited and now doesn't have any iffy string comparisons.