# result of logical operation

Tags: java, error-handling, logical-operators

> For the logical operators, the operands must be of the type **boolean**

Suppose the following code:-

```
int p,q;

p=1;

q=1;

System.out.println("The result is : "+(p&q));
```

### output

The result is : **1**

My question is that in the above code, neither of the two variables is of the type **Boolean**. Then why this code is not producing error?

Also

```
System.out.println(" This is an error : "+(!p));
```

Why this statement is producing an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the symbol used for it looks similar, this is not a boolean operation,
it's a bitwise operation and returns an `int`, not a `boolean`. See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Note that you used `&` (bitwise AND) and not `&&` (logical AND).

Comment: Note that && cannot be applied to int operands.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, if tried on int operands the `&&` will generate a compilation error.

Comment: `&&` is not logical AND, but *conditional* AND. `&` is both logical and bitwise AND, depending on operand type.

Comment: What if I would have declared the above two variables as Boolean.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik OK, this subtle terminological note is taken.

Comment: @kevingomes Then I think auto-unboxing would have taken place, the `Boolean`s would have been turned into `boolean`s, and then & would have had identical behavior to &&. Try it out. See also Marko's note.

Comment: It's not just about terminological subtleties. Your answer implies that `&` is *not* logical AND, whereas in fact it is (`true & false` is a legal boolean expression). Also, `a && b` has different semantics from `a & b`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, OK, because its operands are boolean, it produces a boolean. But normally if one wants a "logical operation", one would use: `true && false`, not `true & false`. Right?

Comment: One would *most of the time* use that, but there are certain cases where you really do want `true & false`.

Comment: @peter.petrov `true && false` and `true & false` both will produce same output. The only difference is that the first one is a case of short circuit logical operator

Comment: @kevingomes I see, OK :) There we go, I also learned something (something well-forgotten probably). You're absolutely right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Answer (score 2):

`p&q` is bit-wise AND of two integers, not a logical operator.

`!p` is invalid since there is no `!` unary operator on integers. `!` is only defined for booleans.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is bit-wise AND operator.

> Binary AND Operator copies a bit to the result if it exists in both operands

For instance in your case.

p = 1 (int) = 0001 (binary)
q = 1 (int) = 0001 (binary)

```
   0001

 & 0001
---------
   0001
```

resulting to 0001 = 1 in int.

`&&` on the other hand is logical operator and requires boolean operands.

> Called Logical AND operator. If both the operands are non-zero, then the condition becomes true.

Further `!` is also logical operator and required boolean operands.

> Called Logical NOT Operator. Use to reverses the logical state of its operand. If a condition is true then Logical NOT operator will make false.

For reference, [visit this site.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)