# Precedence order between || and && - java

Tags: java

As of my under standing `&&` has a higher precedence than `||` given with the following code

```
    static boolean a;
    static boolean b;
    static boolean c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean d = (a = true) || (b = true) && (c = true);
        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + " ");

    }
```

the output of this code is `true false false`, since there are parentheses I assume that the assignment of `true` to variables a,b and c will be first executed before the executing the expressions for `&&` and `||` which is on my understanding is like (a = true) || ((b = true) && (c = true)) but based on the output it seems that after assigning `true` to variable a the left side of `||` has been executed already and thus not execute the rest of the code. Does it mean that `||` has overridden the `&&` since the left side has been executed?

Comment: Don't confuse precedence with order of execution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java logical operator short-circuiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Comment: That cannot be the output of your code because `a = true` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what do you mean execution over precedence?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: ...and is why the other two assignments don't happen, hence the `false false` after the `true`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder interesting, due to the short circuit evaluation.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Exactly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, [`&&` has higher precedence than `||`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). All that means is that your statement

```
boolean d = (a = true) || (b = true) && (c = true);
```

is equivalent to

```
boolean d = (a = true) || ((b = true) && (c = true));
```

it doesn't mean the right side of `||` will be evaluated first. Things are evaluated left to right. Since `||` short circuits and [`a = true` evaluates to `true`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26), it doesn't need to evaluate the right hand side of `||`.

The rest of the class variables are initialized to the default value of `false` (for `boolean` values).

Comment: so you mean that the precedence is just a way on how the expressions will be group and evaluated, not the way that since it has higher precedence it will be executed first? Unless if they are group explicitly then the results will vary. right?

Comment: @anathema Precedence simply defines how operands will be assigned to operators.

Comment: I think this statement helps me understand what you said earlier "When Java sees a && operator or a ||, the expression on the left side of the operator is evaluated first.". @SotiriosDelimanolis