# SONAR complaining to change the condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false"

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

```
public String generateURLSafeToken(String username, char[] password) throws CredentialTokenException {
    this.tokenValid = false;

    String token = null;
    if ((username.length() < 1) || (username == null)) {
        throw new CredentialTokenException("Username cannot be an empty string or null.");
    }
    if ((password.length < 1) || (password == null)) {
        throw new CredentialTokenException("Password cannot be an empty or null.");
    }
```

> I am facing this error in line 4 and line 7 (username == null and password == null)

And I need this part in my code. I am trying isEmpty() instead of null but facing problems in that also . What is an alternate way or the solution to fix this SONAR error

Comment: Swap the conditions around. You should check for `null` before testing the length.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The conditions which always evaluates to `false` are `username == null` and `password == null`.

Let's take the example of `username`. The operator `||` is [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting) meaning it won't evaluate the right hand side if the left hand side is `true`. Basically, there are 2 cases:

- The `username` given is not `null`. The condition `username.length() < 1` is evaluated

  - If the result is `true`, we return directly and enter the `if` branch
  - If the result is `false`, we try to evaluate `username == null`. But since the `username` given is not `null`, this **always** evaluate to `false`.
- The `username` given is `null`. The condition `username.length() < 1` is evaluated. This actually stops right there: it will throw a `NullPointerException` and will not evaluate the right hand side.

Therefore, you can see that whenever the `username == null` condition was actually evaluated, the result was always `false`. This is what the SonarQube warning is telling you.

The solution here is to reverse your 2 conditions. Consider having

```
if (username == null || username.length() < 1)
```

instead. If you start over and go through each case, you'll notice that none of the expressions will always have the same result:

- The `username` given is not `null`. First condition clearly evaluates to `false` and the second is evaluated, which may return `true` or `false`.
- The `username` given is `null`. The first condition clearly evaluated to `true` and short-circuits.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain me my mistake.