# Replace this if-then-else statement by a single return statement

Tags: java, sonarqube

While solving sonarQube issue i face the below warning,does any one tell me how to overcome this warning

Method:-

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Division other = (Division) obj;

        if (divisionId != other.divisionId)
        //getting warning for above if condition

            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Warning :

**Replace this if-then-else statement by a single return statement.**

Description:-

**Return of boolean literal statements wrapped into if-then-else ones should be simplified.**

Answer (score 21):

Well, you can replace:

```
if (divisionId != other.divisionId)
    return false;
return true;
```

with the equivalent:

```
return divisionId == other.divisionId;
```

This will return `false` if `divisionId != other.divisionId` and `true` otherwise.

Comment: @h36p If the condition is `false`, `false` will be returned by the method.

Comment: As @Usagi answered, you don't need to cast the instance in a separate statement. Since it is used only once you can do `return divisionId == ((Division)obj).divisionId;`

Answer (score 5):

I received a similar kind of warning message when using sonarlint "Return of boolean expressions should not be wrapped into an "if-then-else" statement"
this was my code previously,

```
if (val.isEmpty()) {
    switchCompat.setChecked( false );
} else {
    switchCompat.setChecked( true );
}
```

now i changed it to,

```
boolean checked = val.isEmpty();
switchCompat.setChecked( checked );
```

According this question, it is similar to,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Division other = (Division) obj;
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    else if (obj == null)
        return false;
    else if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    else if (divisionId != other.divisionId)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Similarly, it can be resolve like this,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean success;
    Division other = (Division) obj;

    if (this == obj)
        success = true;
    else if (obj == null)
        success = false;
    else if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        success = false;
    else if (divisionId != other.divisionId)
        success = false;
    else
        success = true;
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Sonar Qube Rule:**[`squid:S1126`](https://sbforge.org/sonar/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1126)** - ***Return boolean expressions instead of boolean literal***

In SonarQube, analyzers contribute rules which are executed on source code to generate issues. There are four [`types of rules`](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/rules/):

- Code Smell (Maintainability domain)
- Bug (Reliability domain)
- Vulnerability (Security domain)
- Security Hotspot (Security domain)

```java
Noncompliant Code Example      |  Compliant Solution
---------------------------    |  ----------------------------
boolean foo(Object param) {    |  boolean foo(Object param) {
    /*Some Condition*/         |    boolean expression = false;
    if(param == null) {        |    if(param != null) { // param == null - squid:S4165
        return true;           |        //expression = true; //(squid:S4165)
    }                          |    //} else {
                               |        if(/**/) { // Compliant
    if(/**/){/* Noncompliant*/ |            expression = true; 
        return true;           |        } else if(/**/) {
    } else if(/**/) {          |            expression = true;      
        return true;           |        } else if(/**/) { // squid:S1871
    } else if(/**/) {          |            expression = true;      
        return true;           |        } else { // To avoid else.
    }                          |            expression = false;
    return false;              |        }
}                              |    }
                               |    return expression;
                               |  }
```

**[`squid:S1871`](https://sbforge.org/sonar/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1871)** - Two branches in a conditional structure should not have exactly the same implementation: When multiple `else if() {  }` same code inside the block to overcome this problem above we use extra `else {}` block with different implementation.

---

SonarSource<sup>[rules](https://rules.sonarsource.com/)</sup>, making Code Analyzers - Quality software comes from quality code

- [**SonarQube**](https://www.sonarqube.org/) Continuous Code Quality - Analyze code in your, on-premise CI. For Online Use SonarQube [as a Service](https://sonarcloud.io/about/sq)
- Use [**Sonarlint**](https://www.sonarlint.org/) which Catches the issues on the fly, in your IDE.

See also:

- [Useless "`if(true) {...}`" and "`if(false){...}`" blocks should be removed](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Bug/RSPEC-1145)
- [Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39491641/5081877)

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure of your intent for the if-statements that return false but it seems as if you could simply always return false unless "this == obj".

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This same thing could be accomplished with one line

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this == obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This must work :

```
return this == obj
        ? true
        : obj == null
            ? false 
            : getClass() != obj.getClass()
                ? false
                : divisionId != ((Division)obj).divisionId
                    ? false : true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
return null != obj && this == obj || getClass() == obj.getClass() &&
       this.divisionId == ((Division) obj).divisionId;
```