# How to return boolean "if-then-else" statement in a single return

Tags: java, sonarqube, return, boolean, sonarlint

I am getting a sonar issue of **Replace this if-then-else statement by a single return statement.** As I have three conditions in the if condition, how can I return this without if-else?

```
  public boolean isDateRangeExceedOneYear(CardPluginInterface plugin, Date begin, Date end)
  {
    if (!DateTimeToolkit.getInstance().isEmpty(begin)
        && ((CardValidatorInterface) plugin).isValidateYearDateRangeFor()
        && DateTimeToolkit.getInstance().compare(
        DateTimeToolkit.getInstance().add(new DateTime(begin, new Time((short) 0, (short) 0, (short) 0)), 1, 1).date,
        end) <= 0)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace this if-then-else statement by a single return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817581/replace-this-if-then-else-statement-by-a-single-return-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the above you can use

```
return !DateTimeToolkit.getInstance().isEmpty(begin)
    && ((CardValidatorInterface) plugin).isValidateYearDateRangeFor()
    && DateTimeToolkit.getInstance().compare(
    DateTimeToolkit.getInstance().add(new DateTime(begin, new Time((short) 0, (short) 0, (short) 0)), 1, 1).date,
    end) <= 0;
```