# java - What does || mean in a conditional statement?

Tags: java

What does this mean:

`if (value > 10 || value == 20) {`

Any answer would be nice. thanks!

Comment: a Logical or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: Have you googled at least? Read documentation at first.

Comment: This is the kind of question that should be closed right now.

Comment: see this link please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Comment: It’s not so easy to google `||`, @AndriiAbramov. It’s true that very many of us learned this as one of the very basics of Java, though (and/or other programming languages with related syntax).

Comment: You could just read the Java documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24

Answer (score 1):

It means OR. 
If one of these two options will be true, the if statement will be true.

Note:
both && = AND and || = OR have short evaluation. So if there if other conditions can't change status it won't continue.

http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~lennox/3101-03/class1-slides/logical.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html :

> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR
>   operations on two boolean expressions. These operators exhibit
>   "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is
>   evaluated only if needed.
>
> && Conditional-AND || Conditional-OR

Comment: @BackSlash see this link and the first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 I know the operator short-circuits, but it's a side effect due to logical operations. Those are called conditional operators, not short-circuiting operators. And `|` is not a *plain* or, it's a bitwise or, which is different. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: `|` is a "plain OR" - not a bitwise OR when used with boolean operands https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2

Comment: @LewBloch He can easy google it when he knows now what is it. But link added. And in most cases you really don't care that it is short-circuited. Java have only one logical or and the operator for it is ||. Fact that is short-circuited is just way how is logical or implemented in java. It is just optimalimalization which can speed up resolution of long conditions if the result is known earlier so there is not needed to evaluate the rest. 
Both AndriiAbramov and LewBloch flagged for rude behavior.

Answer (score 1):

|| is a short circuit 'or' boolean operator

If the expression on the left hand side evaluates to true there is no need to evaluate the expression on the right as the condition has already been met

Answer (score 0):

It is an OR conditional Statement. In your particular case, the statements inside the if block will be executed, if the value is more than 10 or if it is equal to 20. 
Hope this explains what you intended to ask.