# Vue.js - error when rendering component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The data is on firebase, and I want to show only 1 object with [objectNumber] see  `{{ligler[1].name}}` in the template, but when I do this it works but I get errors:

- **Error when rendering component**
- **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

I think, the problem is that the data loaded before the component.

When I use v-for, it show the name off all objects without errors, but I only want to show one object.

The template looks like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <h1>{{ligler[1].name}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

the script:

```
<script>
import Firebase from 'firebase'

let config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
}

let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = app.database();

let ligRef = db.ref('ligler');

export default {
  name: 'app',
  firebase: {
    ligler: ligRef
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to add v-if to the h1, but that doesn't work.

How can I fix this errors?

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(ligRef);` ? put this line right before export

Comment: U {u: Te, path: L, m: ee, Nc: false, then: undefined…}


is the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a null check like this:

```
<h1>{{ligler[1] && ligler[1].name}}</h1>
```

Using `&&` or `||` are called logical operator [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) meaning they don't evaluate the right hand side if it isn't necessary. This is [widely used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/1610034) due to it's brevity.

Here if `ligler[1]` is undefined, it will not evaluate `ligler[1].name` and you will not be getting the error, which is equivalent of putting a if before accessing the inside properties.

It makes more sense to use `v-if` if you have more component where you access other properties of `ligler[1]` as well, otherwise above code is better.

```
  <div v-if="ligler[1]">
    <h1>{{ligler[1].name}}</h1>
    <h1>{{ligler[1].age}}</h1>
    <h1>{{ligler[1].etc}}</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: this works!!!! can you explain why I must add ligler[1] &&? Just to identify ligler?

Comment: thanks!!! v-if="ligler[1]" is also working, which one is better to use?

Comment: @Saurahbh, I have one question more.. in my data I have ligler[1].currentWeek and ligler[1].weeks


how can I set currentWeek as variable to use this to show the current week in ligler[1].weeks?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can simplify this by using `v-if`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" v-if="ligler[1]">
    <h1>{{ligler[1].name}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: this works! is this solution better then <h1>{{ligler[1] && ligler[1].name}}</h1> ?

Comment: @Can It depends. If the whole component depends on `ligler[1]` then use `v-if`, if it is only a small part of the component use `&&`.