# Why can't a perform pop() inside an add() for a stack

Tags: java

I wrote up a postfix calculator for boolean expressions given that it was in postfix form. The first time I went about writing it, I used the expression

```
s.add(s.pop() [operation] s.pop());
```

where `s` is my stack and the `operation` is `and`, `xor`, or `or`.

For some reason, the `pop` methods did not seem to peel of the value from the stack, so I instead rewrote this operation using two boolean variables: `b1` and `b2`. These variables contained the popped values which then are passed through the `add` method with the proper operation.

```
if(str.equals("or")){
    boolean b1 = s.pop();
    boolean b2 = s.pop();
    s.add(b1 || b2);
    //out.println(s);
}
```

Why couldn't I use the first statement mentioned?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: How are you declaring the stack?

Comment: Stack<Boolean> s = new Stack<Boolean>();. It is supposed to be reassigned to a new stack each time it looks at a new expression, but I know for sure that part works.

Comment: when using ``||`` and the left value is ``true`` (which happens when the left ``s.pop()`` returns true), the right side is not evaluated. When the right side is a method call such as ``s.pop()``, this leads to the value remaining on the stack since ``pop()`` is not called.

Comment: @f1sh Thank you so much!

Comment: @IanLimarta you're welcome. Omitting the evaluation of un-needed values (which is what happens here) is called short-circuiting. If you want to read more about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Comment: "Why couldn't I use the first statement mentioned?" because `and`, `xor` or `or` are not valid operators in Java, use `&`, `^` and `|` instead... [:-|

Comment: @f1sh you should write that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from my comments since it's now considered an answer:

When using `||` and the left value is `true` (which happens when the left `s.pop()` returns `true`), the right side is not evaluated. When the right side is a method call such as `s.pop()`, this leads to the value remaining on the stack since `pop()` is not called.

Omitting the evaluation of un-needed values (which is what happens here) is called short-circuiting. If you want to read more about it: [Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)