# Why does my Java method reach for a non existant int[0]?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Here is my method to merge two sorted arrays:

```
public static int[] AddString(int[] a, int[] b, int pos, int n){

    if(n > 1){
        if(a[0] > b[0] && !(a.length == 0)){
            c[pos] = b[0];
            b = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length);
        }else{
            c[pos] = a[0];
            a = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length);
        }
        AddString(a, b, pos + 1, n - 1);
    }
    return c;
}
```

I need to combine two sorted arrays. These are the arrays:

```
static int[] c = new int[String1.length + String2.length];
static int[] array1 = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
static int[] array2 = new int[]{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024};
```

Line used to invoke AddString:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(AddString(String1, String2, 0, n)));
```

Now my application returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:21)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.AddString(Main.java:28)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

I understand this is because my application is working with a non existant array index but I don't understand where this happens. The problem occurs when array1 is empty. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Array3 BTW:     static int[] c = new int[String1.length + String2.length];

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not good with debugger but i know the error happens when array1 is empty and the method still tries to cut it down.

Comment: @Mike So learn how to use a debugger

Comment: A debugger is useful, but a lot of print statements can also help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[0] > b[0] && !(a.length == 0)` is causing the out of bounds exception

Looking into it, you're first accessing `a[0]`, then `b[0]` before checking any length values

Instead you may want `a.length > 0 && b.length > 0 && a[0] > b[0]`

Note that java supports short circuiting: [Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

---

After deciphering what exactly you're trying to do, you're fairly close to accomplishing it

Here's a few different ways to merge the two sorted arrays

### 1.

Your implementation fixed up a bit, recursive

```
public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b, int pos, int n)
{
    if(n > 1) //expecting a or b to have an element
        if(a.length > 0)
            if(b.length > 0)
                if(a[0] > b[0]) //a and b have elements
                {
                    c[pos] = b[0];
                    b = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length);
                }
                else
                {
                    c[pos] = a[0];
                    a = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length);
                }
            else //b has no elements, a does
            {
                c[pos] = a[0];
                a = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length);
            }
        else //a has no elements
            if(b.length > 0)
            {
                c[pos] = b[0];
                b = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, 1, b.length);
            }

        merge(a, b, pos + 1, n - 1);
    }

    return c;
}
```

### 2.

Also recursive

```
int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    return merge(a, 0, b, 0, new int[a.length + b.length], 0);
}

int[] merge(int[] a, int aCounter, int[] b, int bCounter, int[] out, int outCounter)
{
    if(aCounter < a.length && bCounter < b.length) //both arrays have elements
        if(a[aCounter] < b[bCounter])
        {
            out[outCounter] = a[aCounter];
            return merge(a, aCounter + 1, b, bCounter, out, outCounter + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            out[outCounter] = b[bCounter];
            return merge(a, aCounter, b, bCounter + 1, out, outCounter + 1);
        }

    if(aCounter < a.length) //only a has elements
    {
        out[outCounter] = a[aCounter];
        return merge(a, aCounter + 1, b, bCounter, out, outCounter + 1);
    }

    if(bCounter < b.length) //only b has elements
    {
        out[outCounter] = b[bCounter];
        return merge(a, aCounter, b, bCounter + 1, out, outCounter + 1);
    }

    //no more elements
    return out;
}
```

### 3.

Non-recursive

```
int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] out = new int[a.length + b.length]; //out array large enough for both contents
    int ac = 0; //a index counter
    int bc = 0; //b index counter
    int outc = 0; //out index counter

    //merge until one array is fully used up
    while(ac < a.length && bc < b.length)
        out[outc++] = a[ac] < b[bc] ? a[ac++] : b[bc++];

    //add the remaining elements to out
    while(ac < a.length)
        out[outc++] = a[ac++];
    while(bc < b.length)
        out[outc++] = b[bc++];

    //return the merged array
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get what you mean but when I use that code I still get the same error message.

Comment: @Mike same error at the same line?  Or are you getting out of bounds on another line?  You may want to also look at `c[pos]` and maybe add `if(pos < c.length)` or similar.  Also note that you potentially call `a[0]` in the else block, which may have been caused by `a` being empty

Comment: You were right, I added the if conditions to the else statement and the error is gone, my array is now filled with 0's though...

Comment: @Mike int arrays are initialized with 0s, are you sure your logic is correct?  What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure it is correct, I'm still a beginner. I try to add two sorted arrays into a third new array for a class about recursion in algorithms.

Comment: @Mike I have added a few different algorithms for merging