# Boolean assign with OR operator

Tags: java

Suppose that i have the following code:

```
    int j = 0;
    boolean x = true, y = false, z;
    z = (x || ((j++) == 0));
    z = (y || ((j += 2) > 0));
```

the **final** value of j will be **2**

z in the 1st assign, will have **true** or **false**, which is true

z in the 2nd assign, will have **false** or **true**, which is true

why the final value is 2?
what is the difference between having true || false and false||true ?

I am not asking about "short-circuit" operators,

I just need more explanation for the assign operator, and how the first j didn't changed the value of **j** and the 2nd did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Comment: `j++` is not evaluated since `x` is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the || operator validates from left to right.

In your case, 
the first condition `true || false`, once `||` finds `true`, it **does not have to check** for the other condition as the result is going to be true regardless. Thats the reason here `x||((j++)==0)` once x = true if figured, the next statement `(j++==0)` is skipped.

the second condition `false || true`, once `||` finds `false`, it **have to check** for next condition.

Ref > https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR
>   operations on two boolean expressions. These operators exhibit
>   "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is
>   evaluated only if needed.