# Short - Circuit OR and OR

Tags: java, if-statement

I am still getting difficulty in understanding the difference between OR and short-circuit OR
Here is the code

```
package if_else_if;

public class if_Else_if {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int month = 4;
        String season;

        if(month == 12 || month == 1 || month == 2)
            season = "Winter";
        else if(month == 3 || month == 4 || month == 5)
            season = "Spring";
        else if (month == 6 || month == 7 || month == 8)
            season = "Summer";
        else if (month == 9 || month == 10 || month == 11)
            season = "Autumn";
        else 
            season = "Bogus month";

        System.out.println("April is a " + season + " month");
    }

}
```

If I simply put 'OR' in place of 'short circuit OR'. I get the same answer.
Is it the execution time that makes the difference. As when we use 'OR', it evaluates all the conditions whereas 'Short circuit OR' skips the subsequent conditions after getting 'month == 4'

Comment: Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Comment: Try `int a = 0; if (a == 0 || 100 / a == 2) { System.out.println("a is 0 or 50); }`. Then replace `||` with `|` and see what happens.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException it shows exception in case of |

Comment: @StephenNollan exactly! And that demonstrates the difference between `||` and `|`.