# Different behavior of OR operator in Java

Tags: java

I have a simple code below:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean v = true;
        v = v || hello();
        System.out.println(v);
    }

    public static boolean hello() {
        System.out.println("inside hello");
        return true;
    }
}
```

and it prints:

```
true
```

But if I change the expression:

```
v = v || hello();
```

to

```
v |= hello();
```

It prints:

```
inside hello
true
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? I assumed that they should have identical behavior but in case of `|=` operator, the short-circuit is not happening.

Comment: Why would you assume they're the same? `v |=` is equivalent to `v = v |`. If you want short-circuiting behavior, you'll have to use the nonexistent `v ||=`.

Comment: This is happening as per the standard short-circuit behavior.

Which says if any condition in || statement becomes true then it will not check further as the result will be true only.

so once it's getting v as true it's returning immediately if you set v = false then it will give the same output as second.

For the second it needs to execute both statements of |= operator and apply the operator.

Comment: @shmosel - The expression `x |=` is what they use for booleans too.

Comment: How did I imply otherwise? You know `|` is also a boolean operator, right?

Comment: @shmosel - Sun's answer is what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) will not cause short circuit :

> First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. If
>   this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression
>   completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not
>   evaluated and no assignment occurs.
>
> Otherwise, the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the
>   right-hand operand is evaluated.
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

In Java `||` has [a short-circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting), the right hand side will not be evaluated if the left hand side is `true` - because the value on the right doesn't matter in that case. So in your first example, `hello()` is never called.

The second example is actually using a different operator, the bitwise OR operator `|` which cannot do the short-circuit because it is for doing bit operations on numbers (but also works on booleans). It will work the same if you expand it out to `v = v | hello()`.