# Recursively returning two methods via &&

Tags: java

I have a method with return statement like this:

```
return method(parameter 1, parameter 2) && method(parameter 2, parameter 1);\
```

However, when looking at my call tree, the second method is never being called (I see no calls with parameters like this). Can anyone explain why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: Because it's a logical and not a boolean and. Put another way `return false && someMethod()` doesn't need to call `someMethod()` to know the return value is `false`.

Comment: How do you determine your call tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible short-circuiting, meaning if `method(parameter 1, parameter 2)` evaluates to `false` then the second method will never be called.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Comment: We usually close questions as duplicates instead of providing answers with an onsite-link.