# Java: boolean expression (x==y && a<b)

Tags: java, boolean-expression

In evaluating the expression `(x==y && a<b)` the boolean expression `x==y` is evaluated first and then `a<b` is evaluated in Java ? (True or False):

I find **False** as the answer but I can't reason it. Moreover, according to my *C/C++* knowledge, if `x==y` evaluated to false, the whole expression `(x==y && a<b)` evaluates to *false* without even moving on to evaluate `a<b`.

If this was similar for `Java`, the answer to the statement must have been **True**.

I couldn't find any suitable explanation for the statement to be *False*, so please help me out.

Comment: [Java Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: This link explains it well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Comment: Just, a clarification, after reading I feel that answer is `True`. Is that correct and the book somehow made a misprint ?