# Is it valid to add a Null check and access the Integer value in the same line of if condition in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, null-check

Say

```
class Person{
    Integer height;
    integer weight;
}
```

is it valid to check like this?

```
Person p = new Person();
if (p.height !=null && p.height >= 1 && p.weight >=1 ){}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Comment: Looks ok to me, be sure that height and weight get initialised, otherwise you will get a null pointer exception

Comment: TL;DR: Yes, this is fine, because once the left hand side of the `&&` is found to be false, the right hand side will not be evaluated. (You only cover height btw, you might need to add a check for weight aswell)

Comment: Yes, because of [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting) of the `&&` and `||` operators doing `if( x != null && x.someMethod())` is valid and safe because if the first part `x != null` evaluates to false (x is null) then the rest of that statement is no longer evaluated because `false && ....` is always false no matter what follows. In your example above however you do not check if `p.weight` isn't null as well. So you might get a `NullPointerException` when the code reaches `p.weight >=1` and weight is `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine, but note that this will still crash with a `NullPointerException` if `p.weight` is null. If you want clean code, consider this question:

What does `height is null` actually mean? Does it mean:

- It is semantically equivalent to 0. (Then, why have it? Make your fields `int`, and set them properly).
- It is unknown.
- It is unset; this is a person who does not want their height publicized.

In particular, given that you are checking for >= 1, apparently you can have a null height, but also a negative height. What is the semantic difference between these two? If there is no difference, why are you allowing a cavalcade of different internal values that nevertheless all boil down to representing the same state? You're signing up for a bevy of checks everytime you interact with these variables, and a combinatorial explosion to test all this. Don't do it this way - create a single value to represent 'invalid' or 'unknown' or 'intentionally omitted' or whatever it is that you need to convey.

*Usually* it leads to better code if you [A] eliminate invalid state as early as possible, which in particular means that you do not need to check for invalid state (here, 0 and negative numbers appear to be intended as invalid) every time you use these variables, and [B] use a sentinel value and not null to indicate a unique state such as 'unset' or 'intentionally not shared'.

In other words:

- Make height and weight private
- Their setters will refuse to set (and throw `IllegalArgumentException` instead) if trying to set 0 or negative height or weight.
- The fields are of type `int`
- Constants exist for the various alternate states.

```
public class Person {
    private static final int UNKNOWN = -1;
    private static final int INTENTIONALLY_OMITTED = -2;
    private int height, weight;

    public Person() {
      this.height = UNKNOWN;
      this.weight = UNKNOWN;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
      if (height < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-positive height");
      this.height = height;
    }

    public void setHeightOmitted() {
      this.height = INTENTIONALLY_OMITTED;
    }
}
```

and so on. Now you can write code that is inherently readable; `null` is nebulous (you'd have to document what it means. Does it mean unset, or invalid, or intentionally omitted? What?), `if (height == INTENTIONALLY_OMITTED)` documents itself, that's a good thing.

Comment: If it is important to note the associativity and short-circuiting behaviour of `&&` operator, then please do for the shake of completeness. +1. I found about the short-circuiting behaviour into the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is valid because Integer is the class representing int.

This is the reason why `Integer` can hold a null value. Comparison at `p.height` and `p.weight` is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because in case of && operation if first condition is true, then after second condition will be checked. If `p.height` is null then, First condition is false so, no other conditions will be checked.

You also have to add null check for `p.width` also.