# Whenever I run the insertion sort program in java, exception occurs .. but i don't know why

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

Below is my code for Insertion Sort and i am facing an exception of array indexing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Insertion_Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=4;
        int ar[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            ar[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            int c=ar[i];
            int j=i-1;
            while(ar[j]>ar[j+1] && j>=0)
            {
                ar[j+1]=ar[j];
                j--;
            }
            ar[j+1]=c;
            
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ar[i]);
        }
        

    }

}
```

**This is the exception i am getting everytime i run this**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 4
    at dfsd.Insertion_Sort.main(Insertion_Sort.java:17)
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. How can you access position -1 of an array?

Comment: Specifically, can you think of a time when `while(ar[j]>ar[j+1] && j>=0)` could cause a problem? `j>=0` will *not* be checked first.

Comment: Which line is line 17? Please don't hide information that is needed for debugging.

Comment: @Swapnil The cause of error is that you have to use `while (j >= 0 && ar[j] > ar[j+1])`. This is necessary. Check here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Comment: @Swapnil You have also used incorrect logic for `insertion sort`. After making the necessary change in `while` loop, the resultant output will be wrong. Do correct it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you should check `j >= 0` first and if that happen check second condition which is  `ar[j] > ar[i]`. but there is another problem `ar` array is changing during the process and you should use `c` instead of `ar[i]` so the condition would be: `j >= 0 && ar[j] > c`. Here is the working version of your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 4;
    int ar[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ar[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int c = ar[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && ar[j] > c) {
            ar[j + 1] = ar[j];
            j--;
        }
        ar[j + 1] = c;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(ar[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

J>=0 should be the first condition. Also you need to check j<n as you are using j+1 in the check (scenario when i reached n-1) to avoid exceptions.
The logic of insertion sort seems to be incorrect.

Comment: *Also you need to check j<n as you are using j+1 in the check (scenario when i reached n-1) to avoid exceptions.* This will not happen since `j` is initialized outside the `while` loop to `j = i-1`.