# How to properly handle if statements containing both null checks and non-null checks together in an OR expression

Tags: java, specifications, operands

I have some code that does the following:

```
if(object == null || object.value.equals(" ")) {
    // do something
}
else {
   // do something else 
}
```

The above seems dangerous to me because if I switched the order of the two conditions or changed this to an AND expression, the code will crash when object is null, but I also read somewhere that Java guarantees operands are evaluated from left to right. That said, I also read do not assume this to be true.

I am confused by all this conflicting advice and wondering whether the above code constitutes a bug. That said, what is the best way to recode this if indeed this is considered bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java `&&` and `||` are **short circuit** (boolean!) operators. So **everything works as assumed**. No unnecessary evaluation running into an error. Some languages Name these *and-then*, *or-else*.

```
boolean newGraphRequired = graphNode == null
    || gaphNode.timeStamp() != moduleNode.timeStamp();
```

Conditions become more straightforward.

Comment: that's exactly the same as if I placed it in the if statement. If this is considered the elegant approach, that's what I prefer :)

Comment: Yes and that is why I added my answer: other answers take a step too far.

Comment: I will edit my code kind sir ... thank you

Comment: Not "shortcut", but [*short circuit*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/256196).

Comment: @Bohemian, thanks for the correction. Imagine propagating prologisms.

Comment: @Lauren_G don’t edit your question to become an answer. It’s confusing readers to have a “question” that says the same as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use below piece of code -

```
  if(object == null || (object != null && " ".equals(object.value))) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
        // do something else 
    }
```

Also Always keep constant values in left side of equals, it will prevent NPE.

For Above code if object is null or object.value is " "(space), it will go inside if otherwise it will go in else.

Comment: what if the value is not a constant?

Comment: If value is not constant then you will have to add one more null check as - object != null && null != object.value && object.value.equals("other non constant value"). Also I am not talking about object.value to be constant, its the other one like space in your case.

Comment: @Lauren_G The reason to do `" ".equals(object.value)` is because `" "` is a "constant", and is guaranteed to not be `null`. The `String#equals(Object)` method will return `false` if the argument is `null` (it won't throw an NPE).

Comment: The `object != null` test is obsolete at this place. It can’t be `null` at this point.