# Check all conditions in an "if" statement?

Tags: if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we usually use `||` not `|`, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference)

Example:

```
if(a && b && d)
{
...
}
```

I need to find out if a language supports checking all conditions in the if statement even if "b" fails. What is this concept called?

Answer (score 14):

No, neither Java nor C++ will evaluate `d`. This is [*short-circuit evaluation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Unless of course you overload `operator&&`. Then both are evaluated. What a nice, straightforward language ;)

Answer (score 3):

No, the binary logical operators are short-circuited.  They evaluate their operands from left to right.  If one of the operands evaluates such that the expression will be false then no other operands are evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The standatd binary opeartions && and || are [short-circuited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  If you want to force both sides to evaluate, use & or | instead of && and ||.  e.g.

```
public class StackOverflow {

   static boolean false1() {
      System.out.println("In false1");
      return false;
   }

   static boolean false2() {
      System.out.println("In false2");
      return false;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("shortcircuit");
      boolean b = false1() && false2();

      System.out.println("full evaluation");
      b = false1() & false2();
   }
}
```