# Efficiency when checking multiple conditions with Java

Tags: java, performance, conditional-statements

I am trying to brush up on my Java since it has been a long time and started working some warm ups at CodingBat.com. (beware spoilers may follow)   ;)

I just did a really simple one that stated:

> Given 2 ints, a and b, return true if one if them is 10 or if their
>   sum is 10.
>
> makes10(9, 10) → true
>   makes10(9, 9) → false
>   makes10(1, 9) → true

My solution was:

```
public boolean makes10(int a, int b)
{
  if( a==10 || b==10)
    return true;
  else
  {
      if( (a+b)==10 )
          return true;
       else
          return false;
  }
}
```

The solution given was:

```
public boolean makes10(int a, int b) {
  return (a == 10 || b == 10 || a+b == 10);
}
```

My question is in the case that a=10 or b=10 will the given solution's if statement terminate and return true or will it first complete checking every condition which would require an unneeded addition operation? (i.e. the a+b)

There is a name for this behavior in C++ but for the life of me I cannot remember what it is.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference

Comment: The behavior is called "Short Circuit" evaluation.

Comment: While the second method is more efficient, take heart that your code is functionally identical :)

Comment: Besides "short-circuiting", I've also seen these called "McCarthy expressions" or "McCarthy evaluation".  The C++ standard doesn't seem to use a special name to refer to it, but the Ada standard calls it a "short-circuit control form".

Comment: Note that there are short-circuit operators (`&&` and `||`) as well as non-short-circuit operators (`&` and `|`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition will be evaluated until one subcondition evaluates to `true`.  If the first condition evaluates to `true` the second and third conditions will not be evaluated.

This is nature of the `or` operator `||`.

Consider the following example:

```
public class Conditions {

    public static boolean isTrue(){
        System.out.println("Is True");
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isFalse(){
        System.out.println("Is False");
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(isFalse() || isTrue() || isTrue()){
            System.out.println("Condition passes");
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Is False
Is True
Condition passes
```

Notice that the third condition which calls the method `isTrue()` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

> Any true will decide the outcome of all ORs (A||B||C||D||E)
>
> Any false will decide the outcome of all ANDs (A&&B&&C&&D&&E)

thus at the first occurrence of the deciding value the statement is evaluated.