# How does JVM run if(codition && false) statements?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

Currently I'm working on a program which has a memory intense checking process. At some point the code looks like this.

```
if(isvalid() && false) //this false is acctually another method which will at this given 
                       //point always return false
{
    //rest ommited
}
```

Will the JVM always check the first method (isValid()) or not since x && false is aways false;

I am not sure because while debugging the debugger is jumping to isValid() method at every iteration.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logcial-operators-short-circuiting and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference for more information about short circuit operations.

Comment: What does your Java language reference say??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will always check `isValid()`. The sematics of `&&` is to evaluate the left part and only if it is `true` look at the right part.

Comment: Hi, so if i write if(false && isValid()) then the method is skipped?

Comment: And please do you have any references that backup your statement?

Comment: Yes. If the left side is false, the right side will be skipped.

Comment: @ZeDonDino The JLS. And you can trivially construct an example as well.

Comment: Here is a reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23

Comment: @ZeDonDino Run `int i=0; if(false && ++i != 0) {}` then print `i`. You'll get your answer.

Comment: If you want the method to be always evaluated (because it has some side effects), you can use & rather than && (but beware of operators precedence) or store the return value of the method in a boolean, and then use the boolean variable in your condition.

Answer (score 3):

The JVM always evaluates the left side of the `&&` or `||` first, and then only evaluates the right side if necessary.  If you think the operation on the right of an `&&` is more likely to return false, then you should switch them around and put it first.

More details: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23

> At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; if
>   the result has type Boolean, it is subjected to unboxing conversion
>   (§5.1.8).
>
> If the resulting value is false, the value of the conditional-and
>   expression is false and the right-hand operand expression is not
>   evaluated.

Comment: No, one should only switch the operations around to put the *less expensive* test on the left (unless one of the tests *must* go first to "guard" the other).  Of course, "less expensive" must take into account the probabilities of true/false.  If A is false 25% of the time and B is false 100% of the time, A should go first if the time required to evaluate A is less than 1/4 of the time required to evaluate B.

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside bytecode, generated by JDK, you`ll notice that if block content t is omitted.

```
if(isValid() && false){
    System.out.print("qqq");
}
System.out.print("www");
```

bytecode:

```
0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method isValid:()Z
3: ifeq          6                  // no if block content!!!
6: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
9: ldc           #4                  // String www
11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Method will be called, but with no effect on branch logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack<Boolean> nums = new Stack<>();
    nums.push(true);
    System.out.println(nums.pop() && false);
    System.out.println(nums.isEmpty());

    nums.push(true);
    System.out.println(false && nums.pop());
    System.out.println(nums.isEmpty());
}
```

it prints
false
true
false
false

you should be  careful when use false && or ture || in your code，sometimes 为 will not use like this case，but the following case we maybe use；

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack<Boolean> nums = new Stack<>();
    nums.push(true);
    nums.push(false);
    System.out.println(nums.pop() && nums.pop());
    System.out.println(nums.isEmpty());

}
```

it prints 
false
false