# Can I use any 'or' like word in an if else statement (in contentEquals() )

Tags: java, android

I was thinking if we could use 'or' or anything like that in Java Eclipse Android Development when I write this code

```
 if (strName.contentEquals("Hi" or "Hello") {

}
```

Can I do something like this?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Eclipse; please use that tag only for questions about actually using the IDE.

Comment: google would have helped you

Comment: You may want to have a look at [these docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2Fnutsandbolts%2Fopsummary.html&ei=9EAoU43jOoPU2AXfpYCwCQ&usg=AFQjCNHzxxJmqCjY_maGVp83NAZJ2HR0JQ&sig2=BnqSVD0hF2hfuYzj_I-y8g&bvm=bv.62922401,d.b2I)

Comment: Instead of `or` you can use `|` or `||`.. For more information check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: "Can I do something like this?" Why didn't you just try the above code?!

Comment: @NewWorld I tried that code but it didn't work that is why I posted it here.

Comment: @PranavGarg Ahh now I understand what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Conditional-OR (||)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator as below...

```
if (strName.equals("Hi") || strName.equals("Hello")) {

}
```

Where, `||` means `OR`.