# Java boolean precedence comparation with ternary operator

Tags: java, boolean, comparator, operator-precedence

I'd found a nice situation that I don't understand at all related to Java boolean operator precedence. I know and verify with the oracle official documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) that && and || have precedence against ternary operator ? :

Now I have a weird line in my code similar to that

```
if (a.getItem() != null && a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null?true:a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue())
{
......
}
```

What I get, well, a nice java.lang.NullPointerException at a.getItem().getOtherItem() becouse a.getItem() is null. How I can solve it, encapsulate it between parenthesis

```
if (a.getItem() != null && (a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null?true:a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue()))
{
......
}
```

So my question is why I get a NullPointerException if I follow the Oficial Documentation previously linked && has precedence against ?: and && is short circuit evaluated (answered also here in some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference)).

Comment: The Elvis operator is something different -- the null coalescing operator -- and it doesn't exist in Java.

Comment: Yes, for that reason I use -- a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null -- insted -- a.getItem().getOtherItem()? --, I know the elvis operator in java is boolean. But I guess that will affect the operator precedence

Comment: `:` is used to make a `if-else` statement, boolean running = value1.equals("run")? true `:` false;

Comment: @kszosze I think you're misunderstanding: there is nothing called an Elvis operator in Java, that's not a feature that Java has.

Comment: So that `code`if-else`code` has more precedence that && operator? in that case.. why when I encapsulate it between `code`( )`code` works fine.

Comment: @PatrickCollins ok I used bad the name. No Elvis operator, then I must say ternary operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are confused about what “higher precedence” means. Let’s explain with a simple example:

The operator `*` has higher precedence than the operator '+'. This means that the expression `a*b+c` is evaluated like `(a*b)+c`. The same applies to the `&&` operator and the ternary operator:

`&&` has higher precedence than the operator `? :`. This means that the expression `a&&b?c:d` is evaluated as `(a&&b)?c:d`.

---

Hence the operator precedence works as documented in your example. It does exactly what you requested:

```
if (a.getItem() != null && a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null?
                                       true:a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue())
```

If `a.getItem()` *is not null and* `a.getItem().getOtherItem()` *is not null* evaluate to **true**, *otherwise* to `a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue()`. So when either of the values is null, the code will attempt to evaluate the third term which will yield to a `NullPointerException`.

It’s not clear what you actually want to achieve. In your second example you say:

```
if (a.getItem() != null && (a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null?
                            true: a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue()))
```

so you want to interpret the case when `a.getItem()` is `null` as `false` but in the braced term you request to interpret the case when `a.getItem().getOtherItem()` is not `null` as `true` while the case that `a.getItem().getOtherItem()` **is** `null` should cause `getSomevalue()` to be called on the reference that you just have proven to be `null`.

What you most likely want to do is to evaluate `a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue()` *if the all values are not null*:

```
if (a.getItem() != null && a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null?
                                     a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue(): false)
```

---

Note that you can express the same without the ternary operator at all. The equivalent statement would be:

```
if (a.getItem() != null && a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null
                        && a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue())
```

---

In the case the fall-back value ought to be `true` like in

```
if (a.getItem() != null && a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null?
                                     a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue(): true)
```

the same can be expressed as

```
if (a.getItem() == null || a.getItem().getOtherItem() == null
                        || a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue())
```

Whenever you see `true` or `false` in a compound `boolean` expression you can be sure that there is something wrong.

Comment: The example was only an easy way to express the question. I know I can rewrite with the ternary operator. Just happen that I notices that making some tests looking for an error. The main question is if && has precedence over ?: and && is a short circuit operator why the ternary operator is evaluated if the left branch in the case the left branch is false.

Comment: @kszosze: read my first paragraph. You get completely wrong what *precedence* means. It means that `a && b? c: d` is equivalent to `(a && b)? c: d`. And short circuiting means, that the evaluation of `b` can be skipped, nothing else. Your expectation is the opposite, that would be the case if `? :` had a higher precedence.

Comment: Holger ok, I got it  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The general use case for `?` is to replace an `if` in a simple assignment branch, something like:

```
int a;
if(isOdd(b) || isPrime(b))
{
  a = b;
}
else
{
  a = -b;
}
```

into simply

```
int a = isOdd(b) || isPrime(b) ? b : -b;
```

And for this use case, it makes sense that `&&` and `||` have precedence over `?`.

The confusion arises only if `?` returns `boolean`, the way you use it inside an `if`, which in my experience is very rare.

Comment: I know the way I make the example is strange. That line was only an example making some test to catch an error, and see this. As you say `code`&&`code` has precedence over `code`?:`code` and `code`&&`code` is a short circuit evaluated, so I don't understand why I get a NullPointerException if no use curve brackets

Answer (score 0):

iI'd say that in your if statement

```
if (a.getItem() != null && a.getItem().getOtherItem() != null?true:a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue())
```

the following most inner part must be evaluated first

```
null?true:a.getItem().getOtherItem().getSomevalue()
```

so that the following part can be put together

```
if (a.getItem() != nulla.getItem().getOtherItem() !=<result_from_most_inner_part>)
```

In any case this if statement is ugly. Make the code rather readable and the compiler will do its part :P

Comment: Why the most inner part must be evaluated first if the precedence say the the left branch must be executed first and the `code`&&`code` is a short circuit operator. Don't find any sense.