# Java single pipeline operator (expression | expression)

Tags: java

I was looking at the android source code today and I found this:

```
if (mLeftDragger.continueSettling(true) | mRightDragger.continueSettling(true)) {
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
}
```

The return type of both these methods is boolean.
What is the purpose of this operator and what happens there actually?

Comment: I'm not sure that is really a duplicate, because the linked question answers the question of what `|` does for integer operands, but not for boolean operands.

Comment: It is bitwise OR for integer arguments, or non-short-circuit OR for boolean arguments.

Comment: Described [here][1].
The difference between | and || is that the former is not short-circuit... so even if the first operand is true, the rest will still be evaluated. I believe this is not described in the linked question...?


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2

Comment: It means "or", similar to `||`, but *both* operands will be evaluated.  This means that `continueSettling` is called on both objects, no matter whether it returns `true` or `false` for `mLeftDragger`.  The result is `true` if either method returns `true`.

Comment: I feel like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7101992/1079354) is a suitable duplicate to this.  It deals directly with booleans.

Comment: @Makoto Use your hammer!

Comment: How was I supposed to search for this question by the single-character string of "|". Give me a break :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  I wanted to wait for a relatively simple quorum on the matter.

Comment: You know, you could actually look it up in a Java reference.

Comment: @ajb -  A bool is simply a 1-bit integer.

Comment: @Hot Licks--Correct, in C++.  Java does not have a `bool` type, and its `boolean` type is not simply an integer (and cannot be converted to or from one with a cast), although there is an obvious relation between booleans and the subset {0,1} of integers.  So because of that, I don't really consider the _originally_ linked question to be a duplicate since it doesn't deal with `true` and `false` at all.  (The duplicate question has changed since my first comment.)

Comment: @ajb - The reason that boolean is treated a little differently in Java is so that it's easy to require only a boolean value in an `if` statement or for the "logical" operators.  This, among other things, allows the compiler to diagnose `if (a = b)` as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` short circuits where as `|` does not.  Short circuiting is when the right hand expression does not get evaluated if there is no need for it to be evaluated.  `|` will calculate all Boolean expressions (left to right).  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759917/2498729).

Comment: Oh, the gracious down vote (and even more gracious missing explanation).

Comment: Not that I am downvoter, but if you know that answer has already been given then you should vote to close (or flag) question as duplicate rather than reposting answer.