# Java doesnt continue after while ()

Tags: java, while-loop

i just started with Java and wanted to write a code that tells me if something is a primenumber or not. But after i insert the number it gets stuck on the while function. What did I do wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Primenumber {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double number1, rest, x;
    boolean prime;

    number1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert a number: "));
    x = 2;
    rest = (number1 % x);

    while (rest != 0 | x == (0.5 * number1)) {
      x = x++;
      rest = (number1 % x);
    }
    if (rest == 0) {
      prime = false;
    } else {
      prime = true;
    }
    if (prime == true) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number1 + " is a prime number ");
    } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number1 + " is not a prime number");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Be careful for floating point errors!

Comment: either that, or you're running in an infinite loop

Comment: Why on earth do you use `double` for judging if something is a prime number?

Comment: There´s also not really any need for a floating point number if you check if the number is prime.

Comment: `x = x++;` seems strange and would cause undefined behavior if this were C code. Do you mean `x++;` or `x = x + 1;`?

Comment: `x` is never changing...`x = x++` is the same as `x = x`. Do what @MikeCAT said `x++;`.

Comment: x = x++; is HELL, do not use % on floating poins number. Integer.parseInt could be enough?

Comment: Please don't you ever write `if(prime == true)` again, please...

Answer (score 1):

```
while (rest != 0 || x <= (0.5 * number1)) {
    x++;
    rest = (number1 % x);
}
```

Two changes `|` is not what you want. `||` is what you are looking for (aka OR).

Also you don't want `x == (0.5 * number1)`. This is the actual cause of your eternal while loop.

Finally change your `double number1` to `int number1`, as an object it makes more sense.

Oh and like the comments mentioned `x++;` is what you want.

Edit: People commenting are correct `|` and `||` are both OR. However as this answer explains [Difference between | and || in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference) it's a matter of if you want to short circuit the OR or not.

Comment: I'm not so good at Java, but using `|` for `boolean` seems valid. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/d2GBlbdI4lrlGTw0

Comment: `|` vs `||` doesn't matter here really, neither operand has a side effect.

Comment: `|` is technically also an `OR`, just that it does check the second condition aswell if the first one is true.

Comment: Note: changing `double number1` to `int number1` is good because this change to this code will also change types of `rest` and `x` to `int`.

Comment: @Andy Turner ... it is just important that the second operand not have a side effect. The first operand will be evaluated in both the cases ;)

Comment: When x == (0.5 * number1) is wrong, what should I use instead? Edit: nvm I saw your change.

Comment: `x <= ` will basically keep looking until x is no longer less then half of `number1`