# & vs | in java, which one should be used and when?

Tags: java, operators

I understand the difference between `&&` and `&`, and `||` and `|`. But what about `|` and `&`, don't they do the same thing?

---

I mean, won't these two `if` be statements  the same?

```
if (a | !b)
  //Code here
if (a & !b)
  //Code here
```

`||` says only if boolean 1 is `false`, then try boolean 2.

`&&` says only if boolean 1 is `true`, then try boolean 2.

---

However, *according my information*,:

`&` says even if boolean 1 is `false` or `true`, evaluate the next statement.

`|` says even if boolean 1 is `false` or `true`, evaluate the next statement.

---

Am I incorrect? If not, are there any other differences between `&` and `|`? All I've found by research was the difference between `&&` and `||` and I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: You are not incorrect that `&` and `|` evaluate both operands unconditionally, but clearly `if (a | !b)` is not the same as `if (a & !b)`: if both `a` and `b` are `true`, then `a | !b == true`, and `a & !b == false`.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Did you read my question? I specifically said ***"All I've found by research was the difference between && and || and I couldn't find anything else."***

Comment: And that post explains that the differences are BITWISE vs BOOLEAN as well as the short-circuiting

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah, Sorry. Well the title is certainly confusing, I thought that was && vs & and || vs |

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101992/why-do-we-usually-use-not-what-is-the-difference) has some decent information about `|` and `&` as boolean operators

Comment: You can read the [**JLS 15.22.2**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2) for the answer you are looking for

Comment: OK, I got extremely confused. Lets say I have `if(true | true)`,  will it pass? And if I have `if(false | false)`, will it pass? Why? Can someone give me a decent example of when they differ? (@AndyTurner 's example is good, but I got mixed up too)

Comment: @AbAppletic `true | true == true`, `false | false == false`.

Comment: @AndyTurner And if we use this with `&`, then `true | true == false` and vise versa?

Comment: @AbAppletic No. `true | true == true`, that's the only value it ever has. `true & true == true` also, but that's a different operator. This is just basic boolean arithmetic.

Comment: And can you explain `true | false` and `true & false`? Sorry, I get confused too quickly... I'm just trying to understand something stupid and I can't get it, sorry