# if statement checks for null but still throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In this code.

```
public class Test {
     public static void testFun(String str) {
         if (str == null | str.length() == 0) {
             System.out.println("String is empty");
         } else { 
             System.out.println("String is not empty");
         }
     }
     public static void main(String [] args) {
         testFun(null);
    }
}
```

We pass a `null` value to the function `testFun`. Compiles fine, but gives a `NullPointerException` in runtime, which I did not expect. Why is it throwing an exception, rather than evaluating the `if` condition to `true` and printing "String is empty"?

---

Suppose the value of the actual argument being passed to `testFun` is generated from some process. Assume that mistakenly a `null` value is returned by that process and is fed to testFun. If such is the case, how does one validate that the value passed to the function is null or not?

One (weird) solution may be by assigning the formal parameter to some variable inside the function and then testing it. But if there are many variables passed to the function, that might become tedious and unfeasible. So, how does one check for null values in such a scenario?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The edit shows exactly the difference between code that works and code that doesn't.

This check always evaluates *both* of the conditions, throwing an exception if `str` is null:

```
 if (str == null | str.length() == 0) {
```

Whereas this (using `||` instead of `|`) is *short-circuiting* - if the first condition evaluates to `true`, the second is not evaluated.

See [section 15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24) of the JLS for a description of `||`, and [section 15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2) for binary `|`. The intro to section 15.24 is the important bit though:

> The conditional-or operator || operator is like | (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `StringUtils`:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

if (StringUtils.isBlank(str)) {

System.out.println("String is empty");

} else { 

System.out.println("String is not empty");

}
```

Have a look here also: [StringUtils.isBlank() vs String.isEmpty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419087/stringutils-isblank-vs-string-isempty)

`isBlank` examples:

```
StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true  
StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true  
StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false  
StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that in your code the program is calling 'null.length()' which is not defined if the argument passed to the function is null. That's why the exception is thrown.

Comment: It never gets to that part of the `if` if `str == null`.

Comment: in the if (str == null || str.length() == 0) condition, the second part would never be evaluated if the first is false. If you do want the second part to be evaluated, you would write it as if (str == null | str.length() == 0) so you can get a nullpointer. Don't see why you would want it in this case but in some cases this could be beneficial.

Comment: actually it does. || is lazy, but he uses | which will evaluate both sides

Comment: @baba I got it. Excellent point. `||` works as a short circuit operator, so once evaluated to true it won't reach to next part. As `|` was being used, null.length was evaluated which produced exception

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using the bitwise or operator: `|`. If you use the logical or operator, `||`, your code will work fine.

See also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation
[Difference between & and && in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7199666/758280)

Answer (score 1):

Change Below line

```
if (str == null | str.length() == 0) {
```

into

```
if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
```

now your code will run corectlly. Make sure `str.isEmpty()` comes after `str == null` because calling `isEmpty()` on null will cause `NullPointerException`. Because of Java uses *Short-circuit evaluation* when `str == null` is true it will not evaluate `str.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

The | and & check both the sides everytime.

> if (str == null | str.length() == 0)

here we have high possibility to get NullPointerException

Logical || and && check the right hand side only if necessary.

but with logical operator

> no chance to get NPE because it will not check RHS