# StringUtils.isBlank() vs String.isEmpty()

Tags: java, string, string-utils

I ran into some code that has the following:

```
String foo = getvalue("foo");
if (StringUtils.isBlank(foo))
    doStuff();
else
    doOtherStuff();
```

This appears to be functionally equivalent to the following:

```
String foo = getvalue("foo");
if (foo.isEmpty())
    doStuff();
else
    doOtherStuff();
```

Is a difference between the two (`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank` and `java.lang.String.isEmpty`)?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that there's also a [`StringUtils.isEmpty(foo)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String)) which helps you avoid null pointers, just like `isBlank`, but doesn't check for whitespace characters.

Answer (score 668, accepted):

[`StringUtils.isBlank()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) checks that each character of the string is a whitespace character (or that the string is empty or that it's null). This is totally different than just checking if the string is empty.

From the linked documentation:

> Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.
>
> ```
>  StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
>  StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true  
>  StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true  
>  StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false  
>  StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
> ```

For comparison **StringUtils.isEmpty**:

```
 StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isEmpty("")        = true  
 StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false  
 StringUtils.isEmpty("bob")     = false  
 StringUtils.isEmpty("  bob  ") = false
```

Warning: In **java.lang.String**.isBlank() and **java.lang.String**.isEmpty() work the same except they don't return `true` for `null`.

[`java.lang.String.isBlank()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) (since Java 11)

[`java.lang.String.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

Comment: You couldn't call `.isBlank()` or `.isEmpy()` on a `null` anyways, since they are methods on a `String`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl actually, you can: eg on an uninitialized String object (or one that's explicitly set to null).

Answer (score 168):

The accepted answer from @arshajii is totally correct. However just being more explicit by saying below,

StringUtils.isBlank()

```
 StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true  
 StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true  
 StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false  
 StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```

StringUtils.isEmpty

```
 StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isEmpty("")        = true  
 StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false  
 StringUtils.isEmpty("bob")     = false  
 StringUtils.isEmpty("  bob  ") = false
```

Answer (score 54):

**StringUtils isEmpty** = **String isEmpty** checks + checks for null.

**StringUtils isBlank** = **StringUtils isEmpty** checks + checks if the text contains only whitespace character(s).

Useful links for further investigation:

- [StringUtils isBlank documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String))
- [StringUtils isEmpty documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String))
- [String isEmpty documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

Answer (score 20):

`StringUtils.isBlank()` will also check for null, whereas this:

```
String foo = getvalue("foo");
if (foo.isEmpty())
```

will throw a `NullPointerException` if `foo` is null.

Comment: There is a bigger difference than that; see my answer.

Comment: This is incorrect. String.isEmpty() will return true if it is null. At least if you are talking about the apache.commons.lang version. I'm not sure about the Spring version.

Comment: The meaning of my comment was edited away (to be fair it could have been more clear from the get-go); I was not comparing StringUtils.isBlank() to StringUtils.isEmpty() - rather StringUtils.isBlank() to the OP's value.isEmpty()

Comment: chut's answer is correct. If java String foo is null, then foo.isEmpty() throws NullPointerException. The apache StringUtils.isBlank(foo) returns true even if foo is null.

Answer (score 9):

`StringUtils.isBlank` also returns `true` for just whitespace:

> isBlank(String str)
>
> Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

Answer (score 8):

The only difference between isBlank() and isEmpty() is:

```
StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true //compared string value has space and considered as blank

StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false //compared string value has space and not considered as empty
```

Answer (score 7):

`StringUtils.isBlank(foo)` will perform a null check for you. If you perform `foo.isEmpty()` and `foo` is null, you will raise a NullPointerException.

Comment: There is a bigger difference than that; see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

StringUtils.isBlank() returns true for blanks(just whitespaces)and for null String as well. Actually it trims the Char sequences and then performs check.

StringUtils.isEmpty() returns true when there is no charsequence in the String parameter or when String parameter is null. Difference is that isEmpty() returns false if String parameter contains just whiltespaces. It considers whitespaces as a state of being non empty.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using third party lib, use Java 11 isBlank()

```
    String str1 = "";
    String str2 = "   ";
    Character ch = '\u0020';
    String str3 =ch+" "+ch;

    System.out.println(str1.isEmpty()); //true
    System.out.println(str2.isEmpty()); //false
    System.out.println(str3.isEmpty()); //false            

    System.out.println(str1.isBlank()); //true
    System.out.println(str2.isBlank()); //true
    System.out.println(str3.isBlank()); //true
```

Comment: This one's pretty hard to read. Might I recommend reformatting it similar to how arshajii did?

Comment: This answer doesn't handle the null case.

Answer (score 3):

**The bottom line is :**

```
isEmpty take " " as a character but isBlank not. Rest both are same.
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a third-party library, use Java 11 isBlank()

```
System.out.println("".isEmpty());                      //true
System.out.println(" ".isEmpty());                     //false
System.out.println(('\u0020'+" "+'\u0020').isEmpty()); //false

System.out.println("".isBlank());                      //true
System.out.println(" ".isBlank());                     //true
System.out.println(('\u0020'+" "+'\u0020').isBlank()); //true
```

If you want to use Java 8 and need isBlank function then try to use third-party library **org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils**

StringUtils.isBlank()

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.isBlank(null));      //true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isBlank(""));        //true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isBlank(" "));       //true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isBlank("bob"));     //false
System.out.println(StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ")); //false
```

StringUtils.isEmpty

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty(null));      // = true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty(""));        //= true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty(" "));       // = false
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty("foo"));     // = false
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty("  foo  ")); //= false
```

Comment: You cannot use Java methods (isBlank or isEmpty) on a null String, so are not equivalent to StringUtils library.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String ptext) {
 return ptext == null || ptext.trim().length() == 0;
}

public static boolean isBlank(String ptext) {
 return ptext == null || ptext.trim().length() == 0;
}
```

Both have the same code how will isBlank handle white spaces probably you meant isBlankString this has the code for handling whitespaces.

```
public static boolean isBlankString( String pString ) {
 int strLength;
 if( pString == null || (strLength = pString.length()) == 0)
 return true;
 for(int i=0; i < strLength; i++)
 if(!Character.isWhitespace(pString.charAt(i)))
 return false;
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

StringUtils.isBlank(myStr) checks if the String myStr is whitespace, empty("") or null.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23419120/2227743).

Answer (score -5):

I am answering this because it's the top result in Google for "String isBlank() Method".

If you are using Java 11 or above, you can use the [String class isBlank()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) method. This method does the same thing as Apache Commons StringUtils class.

I have written a small post on this method examples, read it [here](https://www.javastring.net/java/string/java-string-isblank-method-examples).

Comment: Downvoted because it's not true that Java 11's `isBlank` would be equivalent to `StringUtils.isBlank()` due to missing `null` check in the Java 11 version.