# sign-up form validations in java

Tags: java

i have a signup page connected to sql database.now i want to have validations in signup page like firstname,lastname,username etc can not be empty using java how can i do that 
My code is

```
String fname=Fname.getText();
    String lname=Lname.getText();
    String uname=Uname.getText();
    String emailid=Emailid.getText();
    String contact=Contact.getText();
    String pass=String.valueOf(Pass.getPassword());
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zeeshan","root","sHaNi97426");
        pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("Insert into signup1 values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setString(1,fname);
        pstmt.setString(2,lname);
        pstmt.setString(3,uname);
        pstmt.setString(4,emailid);
        pstmt.setString(5,contact);
        pstmt.setString(6,pass);
        int i=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully Registered");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: use proper capitalization and punctuation in your question to make it easier to understand. Otherwise people will ask things like "What is your question?" etc. Besides that: _what did you try?_ Checking a string for `null` or being empty shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

First your question is not direct. Validation occurs before database query. You should not proceed to database `Connetction` or making any query.

What should you do:

```
public static boolean nullOrEmpty(String value) {
        return value == null || value.trim().equals("") ? true : false;
    }
public void yourMethod(){
    try{
        //YourCode Here
        String fname=Fname.getText();

        if(nullOrEmpty(fname)){
            new throw ValidationException("First name should not be null.");
        }
        //YourCode Here
   }catch(ValidationException e){
     System.err.println("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

Check for every string to validate.

Answer (score 0):

that should not be hard, you can do it with simple if and else like below

```
   if(fname != null && fname.isEmpty()){
                throw new Exception(fname+" cannot be empty");
            }else if(lname != null && lname.isEmpty()){
                throw new Exception(fname+" cannot be empty");
            }
   .....
```

as a recommendation you should abstract validation and database access objects . see example of [MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25057/Simple-Example-of-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Design) here

Answer (score 0):

You may do it just by downloading a `jar` named `org.apache.commons.lang` 
[Stringutils Class Reference](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Sample Code

```
    StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
    StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true  
    StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true  
    StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false  
    StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```

or

```
  StringUtils.isEmpty(obj_String); // Another method to check either null or "";
```

Comment: can i add this jar file to netbeans @Vikrant Kashyap

Comment: yes you should add this jar to `lib` Folder First then you should try to Use this class `StringUtils`

Answer (score -1):

To check if a `String` is empty you can use the method `.isEmpty()`. You'll probably want to use `.trim()` first, as this removes all the whitespaces at the beginning and ending of the String. For more options check out the full documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: have you tried this..  `.isEmpty().` may raise an `NullPointerException` if String contains null ==> 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419087/stringutils-isblank-vs-string-isempty

Comment: '.getText()' never returns 'null' if I recall correctly

Comment: have you read this > http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/02/5-ways-to-check-if-string-is-empty-in-java-examples.html

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2016/01/how-to-check-if-string-is-not-null-and-empty-in-java-example.html

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/05/ava-tips-and-best-practices-to-avoid-nullpointerexception-program-application.html try these too