# Conditioning the filters of a java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i'm working on a filter function that can filter with many parameters and to do that i'm using Java Streams. So that is my code :

```
public void filter(String cours,String prof,String salle,String group) {

this.appointments().addAll(getTimeTable().getCreneauxsList().stream()
            .filter(e->e.getProf().equalsIgnoreCase(prof) )
            .filter(e->e.getCours().equalsIgnoreCase(cours) )
            .filter(e->e.getSalle().equalsIgnoreCase(salle) )
            .filter(e->e.getGroup().equalsIgnoreCase(group) )
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

I want to see if one or many the parameters cours,salle,prof,group are null or its trim () = "", it's not worth it to filter with it cause the result is not what i expected to get.

But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: what result are you expecting ?

Comment: In my collection there are some fields that are null so if one of the parameters is null i got these fields but i want if the parameter is null or its trim()="" so there is no filter

Comment: something like `e -> StringUtils.isBlank(prof) || e.getProf().equalsIgnoreCase(prof)`

Comment: So, you wanna get the list of objects whose fields are null or empty strings

Comment: no, the filter to be applied only if the criteria is not blank

Comment: @Wisthler yes that's what i want to do, does StringUtils alreary exist in java?

Comment: StringUtils is part of Apache Commons-Lang: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method to handle the null or empty string during filter like below:

```
public static boolean compareNullableString(String str, String filterStr) {

    return (filterStr == null || filterStr.trim().equals("")) ? true : filterStr.equalsIgnoreCase(str);

}
```

And then modify your code like:

```
this.appointments().addAll(getTimeTable().getCreneauxsList().stream()
                .filter(e->compareNullableString(e.getProf,prof) )
                .filter(e->compareNullableString(e.getCours,cours))
                .filter(e->compareNullableString(e.getSalle,salle) )
                .filter(e->compareNullableString(e.getGroup,group) )
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but `return filterStr == null || filterStr.trim().isEmpty() || filterStr.equalsIgnoreCase(str);` seems more readable

Comment: @ernest_k You are right. That's a good suggestion. It will make the statement brief and more readable. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Strings.isNullOrEmpty()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty(java.lang.String)) from guava:

```
boolean isNullOrEmpty = Strings.isNullOrEmpty(e.getProf());
```

Or there is a set of methods from apache commons:

[`StringUtils.isBlank`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-), [`StringUtils.isNotBlank`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-), [`StringUtils.isEmpty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-), [`StringUtils.isNotEmpty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-)

This might be useful: [StringUtils.isBlank() vs String.isEmpty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419087/stringutils-isblank-vs-string-isempty)

It your case `isNotBlank` exactly what you are looking for:

```
BiPredicate<String, String> myPredicate = (field, eqString) ->
        StringUtils.isNotBlank(field) && field.equalsIgnoreCase(eqString);

    ...
    .filter(e -> myPredicate.test(e.getProf(), prof))
    .filter(e -> myPredicate.test(e.getCours(), cours))
    .filter(e -> myPredicate.test(e.getSalle(), salle))
    .filter(e -> myPredicate.test(e.getGroup(), group))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54731870/11733759) answer can be improved.

Method `compareNullableString` can be as it is. You can get rid of creating List and adding element in `forEach`. Filtering can be also extracted to `Predicate`.

```java
List<String> appointments = this.appointments();

Stream<Predicate<Creneauxs>> filterStream = Stream.of(
        e->compareNullableString(e.getProf,prof),
        e->compareNullableString(e.getCours,cours),
        e->compareNullableString(e.getSalle,salle),
        e->compareNullableString(e.getGroup,group)
);
Predicate<Creneauxs> filter = filterStream.reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(x->false);

getTimeTable().getCreneauxsList().stream()
  .filter(filter)
  .forEach(appointments::add);
```