# What is different between isEmpty and isBlank in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to check the value of a String in my in Android project. I saw two functions to check my String value:

```
item.isBlank()
```

and

```
item.isEmpty()
```

What is difference between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StringUtils.isBlank() vs String.isEmpty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419087/stringutils-isblank-vs-string-isempty)

Comment: @xszym That's a Java question for a different class (same content, of course).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`item.isEmpty()` checks only the length of the the string

`item.isBlank()` checks the length and that all the chars are whitespaces

That means that

- `"   ".isEmpty()` should returns false
- `"   ".isBlank()` should returns true

From the doc of `isBlank`

> Returns true if this string is empty or consists solely of whitespace
> characters.

Answer (score 8):

In future, you can read documentation and see the code from IDE just click Ctrl+B or Command+B. This is written in documantation for isEmpty method:

```
/**
 * Returns `true` if this char sequence is empty (contains no characters).
 *
 * @sample samples.text.Strings.stringIsEmpty
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun CharSequence.isEmpty(): Boolean = length == 0
```

And for isBlank:

```
 * Returns `true` if this string is empty or consists solely of whitespace characters.
 *
 * @sample samples.text.Strings.stringIsBlank
 */
public actual fun CharSequence.isBlank(): Boolean = length == 0 || indices.all { this[it].isWhitespace() }
```