# Any scenario in which String.isEmpty() returns true and String.isBlank() returns false for the same input?

Tags: java, string

Isn't `String.isBlank()` equivalent to `String.isEmpty() + *whitespace only check*`?
While looking at the source code for `String.isBlank()`, it would return true when the length is zero. But I would like to know if there are any scenarios in which `isEmpty()` would return a `true` and `isBlank()` returns a `false` for the same input.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419087/stringutils-isblank-vs-string-isempty) answer your question?

Comment: These border cases are well-explained in the docs. Have you read them? It sounds logical to me that it cannot happen that `isEmpty()` returns `true` and `isBlank()` returns `false` for the same input. But, if you have any doubts, check the docs to see if there is an exception

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper That question is about Commons Lang `StringUtils.isBlank`, not `String.isBlank()`.

Comment: You can look this entry. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23419120/7927573

Comment: @Paul Some of the answers reference `String.isBlank()`. Among them, the accepted answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StringUtils.isBlank() vs String.isEmpty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419087/stringutils-isblank-vs-string-isempty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs say for `isEmpty()`:

> Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.

The docs of `isBlank()`:

> Returns **true if the string is empty** or contains only white space codepoints, otherwise false.

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

So `isBlank()` seems to cover also all cases of `isEmpty()`.

There exists only one string where `isEmpty()` returns `true`, and that is an empty string `""`. `isBlank()` returns `true` if an empty string is provided as parameter.

So: **no**. No case exists where `isEmpty()` returns true and `isBlank()` returns false.

And if it does, it is a software bug, provided that the documentation describes the intended behaviour. Or else you have to ask Schrödinger.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one input for which `isEmpty()` and `isBlank()` produce opposite results, and that's a space:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s = " ";
      System.out.println("isBlank: "+s.isBlank());
      System.out.println("isEmpty: "+s.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

*isBlank: true*

*isEmpty: false*

The opposite case where `isBlank()`returns false and `isEmpty` returns true does not happen, because as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), `isBlank()` returns true only if the string is empty or contains only white space codepoints, and `isEmpty()` returns true if, and only if, `length()` is 0. And there is no case of a string of length 0 that is not considered blank.

Comment: Op seems to know that, but asks for the other way round.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Good catch, I have edited my answer to make it more complete, with links to documentation, and actually answer what OP is asking instead of the more general "when do both methods give different output for the same input".